# How do I calculate the date six months from the current date using the datetime Python module?

Tags: python, datetime

I am using the datetime Python module.  I am looking to calculate the date 6 months from the current date. Could someone give me a little help doing this?

The reason I want to generate a date 6 months from the current date is to produce a *review date*.  If the user enters data into the system it will have a review date of 6 months from the date they entered the data.

Comment: You will have to be more specific : when is six months from march 31th?  And from august 30th?

Comment: Yes the edit helps: it means you can aproximate 6 months to 183 days with no ill effect.  So adding 183 days to today will do the trick.

Comment: The above comments strike me as silly.  The concept of "adding six months" is quite clear -- take the month component and add `6` to it, with support for rolling over the year (and cycling the month back to `1`) if we go past December.  This happens to be exactly what `relativedelta` does and is in fact what every programming language with support for this sort of concept does.

Comment: @KirkWoll: I am sure it is quite clear. But still different for whoever speaks. Python: `date(2015, 3, 31) + relativedelta(months = 6)` gives `datetime.date(2015, 9, 30)`. Perl: `DateTime->new(year=>2000, month=>3, day=>31)->add(months=>6)` gives `2000-10-01T00:00:00`. Php: `date_create('2000-03-31', new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->add(new DateInterval('P6M'))` gives 2000-10-01. Pick your poison.

Comment: @kmkaplan The problem with adding 183 days or similar approaches is that for certain dates they produce an answer which doesn't match ANYONE's definition of what 'adding six months' should be.

Comment: related: [How to convert years to seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32658742/4279)

Comment: ... adding 182 seems more pragmatic for generating a *review date*: it keeps the day of the week intact.

Comment: @Wolf Maybe… It turns out `6*365/12` does give `182` because of integer division ;-)

Answer (score 1359):

I found this solution to be good.  (This uses the [python-dateutil extension](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/))

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

six_months = date.today() + relativedelta(months=+6)
```

The advantage of this approach is that it takes care of issues with 28, 30, 31 days etc. This becomes very useful in handling business rules and scenarios (say invoice generation etc.)

```
$ date(2010,12,31)+relativedelta(months=+1)
  datetime.date(2011, 1, 31)

$ date(2010,12,31)+relativedelta(months=+2)
  datetime.date(2011, 2, 28)
```

Comment: the +6 is an indicator that it could be -6, same thing applies to days and years as well :)

Comment: that's weird, I'm using python 2.7.1 and from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta won't work

Comment: @sliders_alpha You need to install the python-dateutil package (pip install python-dateutil)

Comment: This is the correct solution. If the OP would have asked 6 years instead of 6 months, then the approved answer would fail miserably. So one should keep in mind that the answers are more valuable the more generalized they are.

Comment: Kindly note that the `relativedelta` function also takes in `month` as an argument, which basically replaces / sets / fixes month in the passed date, which is very different than adding more months. Just a forewarning for folks wondering if the function is broken because they forgot the extra *s* in *months*.

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r this comment should be part of the answer- I just spent a frustrating 15 minutes wondering why it wasn't working

Comment: I'm curious: does anyone know why this isn't included by default? Timedelta seems packaged with `datetime` by default. I actually assumed I could pass "months" into timedelta.

Comment: @dTanMan Since it is not clear what should be the result of adding one month to date `(2020, 1, 30)`. Any attempt to solve it is not perfect and will raise a debate. All these corner cases and additional features are left to be covered by the external `dateutil` package.

Comment: wow can't believe i have to scroll down this much

Comment: @dTanMan one challenge with timedelta is that the biggest unit is days, so adding months and years is not straightforward but the .replace() function could work: dateTimeObj = dateTimeObj.replace(year = dateTimeObj.year - 1), though this becomes challenging when adding days months goes past the edge of a month / year

Answer (score 73):

Well, that depends what you mean by 6 months from the current date.

1. Using natural months:

   ```py
   inc = 6
   year = year + (month + inc - 1) // 12
   month = (month + inc - 1) % 12 + 1
   ```
2. Using a banker's definition, 6*30:

   ```py
   date += datetime.timedelta(6 * 30)
   ```

Comment: Could you throw in the half-year definition (183 days) plus the 26 weeks definition, too?  It helps to have them all in one place.

Comment: just a quick remark: I think, for month, the formula would be instead (month + 5) % 12 + 1 b/c for june, your formula gives 0 whereas the expected result is 12... despite this little error, to my mind, your answer is the one that best answers the question

Comment: and same for year: it should be year + (month + 5)/12

Comment: What if the date is 31, and the month six month later can't have 31 days (which is the case for most months with 31 days)?

Comment: 30 days isn't 'the bankers definition'. There are LOTS of ways of counting days for interest payments etc., and the several methods based on 30/360 :) are just a few of them. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention#30.2F360_methods

Comment: Downvote because the first solution ``(day, month, year) = (day, (month+6)%12, year+(month+6)/12)`` can buggy, as it generates invalid dates such as ``(31, 8, 2015)`` -> ``(31, 2, 2016)``

Comment: does not work with python 3. There you get a float year (e.g. 2020.6666666666667)

Comment: @dev-null, just wrap year in `int()`

Comment: @ruslan_krivoshein, ok that works. But I think it would be even better to use the quotient operator // in the last expression: `year + (month + 5)//12`. Then there's no type conversion needed and the purpose is clearer.

Comment: For method 1, the month should be the "old" month variable. Otherwise it's broken. Edit: never mind, it WAS correct but someone changed and broke it.

Comment: @nico-schlömer would you mind to modify it one more time to fix the issue mentioned above? Thanks (I can't edit this answer due to "queue being full".

Comment: @nico-schlömer Sorry I wasn't clear. They were not swapped. The issue is that with the old way, which is `(month, year) = ((month + 5) % 12 + 1, year + (month + 5)/12)`  both variables are changed together, so the new variable of `month` won't be used when evaluating `year`. Your change, which split it into two lines, would have that problem and gives incorrect result. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502268/how-does-pythons-comma-operator-work-during-assignment

Comment: I finally be able to modified it myself, so it should be solved now. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 66):

With Python 3.x you can do it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

date = datetime.now()
print(date)
# 2018-09-24 13:24:04.007620

date = date + relativedelta(months=+6)
print(date)
# 2019-03-24 13:24:04.007620
```

but you will need to install **python-dateutil** module:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: I'd recommend `from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta`. Using `import *` isn't explicit.

Comment: `pd.DateOffset` exactly the same thing in newer `pandas`, `date = date + pd.DateOffset(months=6)` without need to install `dateutil`,  see help

Answer (score 24):

So, here is an example of the `dateutil.relativedelta` which I found useful for iterating through the past year, skipping a month each time to the present date:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> today = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> month_count = 0
>>> while month_count < 12:
...  day = today - relativedelta(months=month_count)
...  print day
...  month_count += 1
... 
2010-07-07 10:51:45.187968
2010-06-07 10:51:45.187968
2010-05-07 10:51:45.187968
2010-04-07 10:51:45.187968
2010-03-07 10:51:45.187968
2010-02-07 10:51:45.187968
2010-01-07 10:51:45.187968
2009-12-07 10:51:45.187968
2009-11-07 10:51:45.187968
2009-10-07 10:51:45.187968
2009-09-07 10:51:45.187968
2009-08-07 10:51:45.187968
```

As with the other answers, you have to figure out what you actually mean by "6 months from now."  If you mean "today's day of the month in the month six years in the future" then this would do:

```
datetime.datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=6)
```

Answer (score 23):

**Python can use datautil package for that, Please see the example below**

It's not Just limited to that, you can pass combination of days, Months and Years at the same time also.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# subtract months
proc_dt = datetime.date(2021,8,31)
proc_dt_minus_3_months = proc_dt + relativedelta(months=-3)
print(proc_dt_minus_3_months)

# add months
proc_dt = datetime.date(2021,8,31)
proc_dt_plus_3_months = proc_dt + relativedelta(months=+3)
print(proc_dt_plus_3_months)

# subtract days:
proc_dt = datetime.date(2021,8,31)
proc_dt_minus_3_days = proc_dt + relativedelta(days=-3)
print(proc_dt_minus_3_days)

# add days days:
proc_dt = datetime.date(2021,8,31)
proc_dt_plus_3_days = proc_dt + relativedelta(days=+3)
print(proc_dt_plus_3_days)

# subtract years:
proc_dt = datetime.date(2021,8,31)
proc_dt_minus_3_years = proc_dt + relativedelta(years=-3)
print(proc_dt_minus_3_years)

# add years:
proc_dt = datetime.date(2021,8,31)
proc_dt_plus_3_years = proc_dt + relativedelta(years=+3)
print(proc_dt_plus_3_years)
```

Results:

2021-05-31

2021-11-30

2021-08-28

2021-09-03

2018-08-31

2024-08-31

Comment: "Python has inbuild libraries for that" -> no, dateutil is not part of the python standard library.

Comment: @Doug thank for correcting me, I didn't notice that. i got it installed long time back.

Answer (score 20):

This solution works correctly for December, which most of the answers on this page do not.
You need to first shift the months from a 1-based index (ie Jan = 1) to a 0-based index (ie Jan = 0) before using modulus ( % ) or integer division ( // ), otherwise November (11) plus 1 month gives you 12, which when finding the remainder ( 12 % 12 ) gives 0.

(And dont suggest "(month % 12) + 1" or Oct + 1 = december!)

```
def AddMonths(d,x):
    newmonth = ((( d.month - 1) + x ) % 12 ) + 1
    newyear  = int(d.year + ((( d.month - 1) + x ) / 12 ))
    return datetime.date( newyear, newmonth, d.day)
```

However ... This doesnt account for problem like Jan 31 + one month. So we go back to the OP - what do you mean by adding a month? One solution is to backtrack until you get to a valid day, given that most people would presume the last day of jan, plus one month, equals the last day of Feb.
This will work on negative numbers of months too.
Proof:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> AddMonths(datetime.datetime(2010,8,25),1)
datetime.date(2010, 9, 25)
>>> AddMonths(datetime.datetime(2010,8,25),4)
datetime.date(2010, 12, 25)
>>> AddMonths(datetime.datetime(2010,8,25),5)
datetime.date(2011, 1, 25)
>>> AddMonths(datetime.datetime(2010,8,25),13)
datetime.date(2011, 9, 25)
>>> AddMonths(datetime.datetime(2010,8,25),24)
datetime.date(2012, 8, 25)
>>> AddMonths(datetime.datetime(2010,8,25),-1)
datetime.date(2010, 7, 25)
>>> AddMonths(datetime.datetime(2010,8,25),0)
datetime.date(2010, 8, 25)
>>> AddMonths(datetime.datetime(2010,8,25),-12)
datetime.date(2009, 8, 25)
>>> AddMonths(datetime.datetime(2010,8,25),-8)
datetime.date(2009, 12, 25)
>>> AddMonths(datetime.datetime(2010,8,25),-7)
datetime.date(2010, 1, 25)>>>
```

Comment: Fixes the "Jan 31 + one month" problem: days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(newyear, newmonth)[1]; newday = min(d.day, days_in_month); (bumps the day down if too big eg Feb 31 to Feb 28/29)

Comment: This worked for me only by converting the newyear to an integer data type

    def AddMonths(d,x):
        newmonth = ((( d.month - 1) + x ) % 12 ) + 1
        newyear  = d.year + int((( d.month - 1) + x ) / 12 ) 
        return datetime.date( newyear, newmonth, d.day)

Comment: Why fiddle around with all these magic numbers when the correct solution has already been implemented in the `dateutil` package?

Comment: @RolandIllig works great for my situation because the tool I'm using does not allow package installation

Comment: how about if the day is 2020-3-1, and i need to go back a full month to get 2020-1-30 or 2020-1-31

Answer (score 20):

For beginning of month to month calculation:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

end_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=delta_period) + timedelta(days=-delta_period)
```

Comment: This isn't the relativedelta solution mentioned above in the comments. Keep scrolling for the solution with 600+ upvotes.

Answer (score 20):

This doesn't answer the specific question (using `datetime` only) but, given that others suggested the use of different modules, here there is a solution using `pandas`.

```py
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

date = dt.date.today() - \
       pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=6)

print(date)

2019-05-04 00:00:00
```

Which works as expected in leap years

```py
date = dt.datetime(2019,8,29) - \
       pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=6)
print(date)

2019-02-28 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 18):

What do you mean by "6 months"?

Is 2009-02-13 + 6 months == 2009-08-13? Or is it 2009-02-13 + 6*30 days?

```
import mx.DateTime as dt

#6 Months
dt.now()+dt.RelativeDateTime(months=6)
#result is '2009-08-13 16:28:00.84'

#6*30 days
dt.now()+dt.RelativeDateTime(days=30*6)
#result is '2009-08-12 16:30:03.35'
```

More info about [mx.DateTime](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/)

Answer (score 16):

There's no direct way to do it with Python's datetime.

Check out the relativedelta type at [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454). It allows you to specify a  time delta in months.

Answer (score 14):

Just use the *timetuple* method to extract the months, add your months and build a new dateobject. If there is a already existing method for this I do not know it.

```
import datetime

def in_the_future(months=1):
    year, month, day = datetime.date.today().timetuple()[:3]
    new_month = month + months
    return datetime.date(year + (new_month / 12), (new_month % 12) or 12, day)
```

The API is a bit clumsy, but works as an example. Will also obviously not work on corner-cases like 2008-01-31 + 1 month. :)

Comment: Error in your code: `new_month % 12` should be `(new_month % 12) or 12`. Otherwise if you try this in November you will get an error. :)

Comment: This is actually much cleaner than the accepted solution. This doesn't require any new import, just basic maths

Comment: return datetime.date(year + (new_month/ / 12), (new_month % 12) or 12, day)

Comment: This didn't handle new_month % 12 == 0, it just skip a whole year

Comment: Doing `new_month / 12` and `new_month % 12` is wrong since month uses a 1-based index.  You need to convert to 0-based indexing, perform division/modulus, and then convert back to 1-based indexing.

Answer (score 14):

I know this was for 6 months, however the answer shows in google for "adding months in python" if you are adding one month:

```
import calendar

date = datetime.date.today()    //Or your date

datetime.timedelta(days=calendar.monthrange(date.year,date.month)[1])
```

this would count the days in the current month and add them to the current date, using 365/12 would ad 1/12 of a year can causes issues for short / long months if your iterating over the date.

Answer (score 11):

Using Python standard libraries, i.e. without `dateutil` or others, and solving the 'February 31st' problem:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def add_months(date, months):
    months_count = date.month + months

    # Calculate the year
    year = date.year + int(months_count / 12)

    # Calculate the month
    month = (months_count % 12)
    if month == 0:
        month = 12

    # Calculate the day
    day = date.day
    last_day_of_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    if day > last_day_of_month:
        day = last_day_of_month

    new_date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    return new_date
```

Testing:

```
>>>date = datetime.date(2018, 11, 30)

>>>print(date, add_months(date, 3))
(datetime.date(2018, 11, 30), datetime.date(2019, 2, 28))

>>>print(date, add_months(date, 14))
(datetime.date(2018, 12, 31), datetime.date(2020, 2, 29))
```

Comment: This has a bug: If the target month is December, it will return a date one year later than needed. Example: `add_months(datetime.date(2018, 11, 30), 1)` returns `datetime.date(2019, 12, 30)` (the year should be 2018, not 2019). So, better use a dedicated, well tested library for this! If you really need to only use standard library modules, see [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35067015/40076).

Answer (score 10):

[Dateutil package](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) has implementation of such functionality. But be aware, that this will be *naive*, as others pointed already.

Comment: dateutil is awesome.  It can be installed with easy_install too.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for suggesting that. That seems to be a god-sent.

Comment: What do you mean by _naive_?

Answer (score 6):

A quick suggestion is [Arrow](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow)

pip install arrow

```
>>> import arrow

>>> arrow.now().date()
datetime.date(2019, 6, 28)
>>> arrow.now().shift(months=6).date()
datetime.date(2019, 12, 28)
```

Comment: Use .datetime to avoid timezone (aware / naive) warning: arrow.now().shift(months=6).datetime

Answer (score 5):

I have a better way to solve the 'February 31st' problem:

```
def add_months(start_date, months):
    import calendar

    year = start_date.year + (months / 12)
    month = start_date.month + (months % 12)
    day = start_date.day

    if month > 12:
        month = month % 12
        year = year + 1

    days_next = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    if day > days_next:
        day = days_next

    return start_date.replace(year, month, day)
```

I think that it also works with negative numbers (to subtract months), but I haven't tested this very much.

Comment: This answer has the merit of correctly solving the problem using only built-in Python libraries. Check stackoverflow.com/a/4131114/302264 for an equivalent but slightly more concise answer.

Comment: What type is `start_date` supposed to have?

Comment: Only works in December, due to the floating-point division `months / 12`.

Answer (score 4):

The QDate class of PyQt4 has an addmonths function.

```
>>>from PyQt4.QtCore import QDate  
>>>dt = QDate(2009,12,31)  
>>>required = dt.addMonths(6) 

>>>required
PyQt4.QtCore.QDate(2010, 6, 30)

>>>required.toPyDate()
datetime.date(2010, 6, 30)
```

Answer (score 3):

Modified Johannes Wei's answer in the case 1new_month = 121.  This works perfectly for me.  The months could be positive or negative.

```
def addMonth(d,months=1):
    year, month, day = d.timetuple()[:3]
    new_month = month + months
    return datetime.date(year + ((new_month-1) / 12), (new_month-1) % 12 +1, day)
```

Comment: It DOESN'T "work perfectly" when the day in the start date is greater than the number of days in the target month. Example: 2001-01-31 plus one month tries to create a date 2001-02-31.

Answer (score 3):

Modified the AddMonths() for use in Zope and handling invalid day numbers:

```
def AddMonths(d,x):
    days_of_month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    newmonth = ((( d.month() - 1) + x ) % 12 ) + 1
    newyear  = d.year() + ((( d.month() - 1) + x ) // 12 ) 
    if d.day() > days_of_month[newmonth-1]:
      newday = days_of_month[newmonth-1]
    else:
      newday = d.day() 
    return DateTime( newyear, newmonth, newday)
```

Comment: This does not seem to consider leap years (29 days in feb).

Comment: Instead get the `days_of_month` with calendar.monthrange(year, month)[-1]

Answer (score 3):

```
import time

def add_month(start_time, months):  

        ret = time.strptime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d')
        t = list(ret)

        t[1] += months

        if t[1] > 12:
            t[0] += 1 + int(months / 12)

            t[1] %= 12

        return int(time.mktime(tuple(t)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime


'''
Created on 2011-03-09

@author: tonydiep
'''

def add_business_months(start_date, months_to_add):
    """
    Add months in the way business people think of months. 
    Jan 31, 2011 + 1 month = Feb 28, 2011 to business people
    Method: Add the number of months, roll back the date until it becomes a valid date
    """
    # determine year
    years_change = months_to_add / 12

    # determine if there is carryover from adding months
    if (start_date.month + (months_to_add % 12) > 12 ):
        years_change = years_change + 1

    new_year = start_date.year + years_change

    # determine month
    work = months_to_add % 12
    if 0 == work:
        new_month = start_date.month
    else:
        new_month = (start_date.month + (work % 12)) % 12

    if 0 == new_month:
        new_month = 12 

    # determine day of the month
    new_day = start_date.day
    if(new_day in [31, 30, 29, 28]):
        #user means end of the month
        new_day = 31


    new_date = None
    while (None == new_date and 27 < new_day):
        try:
            new_date = start_date.replace(year=new_year, month=new_month, day=new_day)
        except:
            new_day = new_day - 1   #wind down until we get to a valid date

    return new_date


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #tests
    dates = [datetime.date(2011, 1, 31),
             datetime.date(2011, 2, 28),
             datetime.date(2011, 3, 28),
             datetime.date(2011, 4, 28),
             datetime.date(2011, 5, 28),
             datetime.date(2011, 6, 28),
             datetime.date(2011, 7, 28),
             datetime.date(2011, 8, 28),
             datetime.date(2011, 9, 28),
             datetime.date(2011, 10, 28),
             datetime.date(2011, 11, 28),
             datetime.date(2011, 12, 28),
             ]
    months = range(1, 24)
    for start_date in dates:
        for m in months:
            end_date = add_business_months(start_date, m)
            print("%s\t%s\t%s" %(start_date, end_date, m))
```

Answer (score 2):

Rework of an earlier answer by user417751. Maybe not so pythonic way, but it takes care of different month lengths and leap years. In this case 31 January 2012 + 1 month = 29 February 2012.

```
import datetime
import calendar

def add_mths(d, x):
    newday = d.day
    newmonth = (((d.month - 1) + x) % 12) + 1
    newyear  = d.year + (((d.month - 1) + x) // 12)
    if newday > calendar.mdays[newmonth]:
        newday = calendar.mdays[newmonth]
        if newyear % 4 == 0 and newmonth == 2:
            newday += 1
    return datetime.date(newyear, newmonth, newday)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution - hope someone will like it:

```
def add_months(d, months):
    return d.replace(year=d.year+months//12).replace(month=(d.month+months)%12)
```

This solution doesn't work for days 29,30,31 for all cases, so more robust solution is needed (which is not so nice anymore :) ):

```
def add_months(d, months):
    for i in range(4):
        day = d.day - i
        try:
            return d.replace(day=day).replace(year=d.year+int(months)//12).replace(month=(d.month+int(months))%12)
        except:
            pass
    raise Exception("should not happen")
```

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1495548/605356), see [parsedatetime](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime). Code example follows. More details: [unit test with many natural-language -> YYYY-MM-DD conversion examples](https://gist.github.com/johnnyutahh/24f9a48a331fd36a4e97#file-parsedatetime_unittest-py), and apparent [parsedatetime conversion challenges/bugs](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime/issues/88).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time, calendar
from datetime import date

# from https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime
import parsedatetime as pdt

def print_todays_date():
    todays_day_of_week = calendar.day_name[date.today().weekday()]
    print "today's date = " + todays_day_of_week + ', ' + \
                              time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

def convert_date(natural_language_date):
    cal = pdt.Calendar()
    (struct_time_date, success) = cal.parse(natural_language_date)
    if success:
        formal_date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', struct_time_date)
    else:
        formal_date = '(conversion failed)'
    print '{0:12s} -> {1:10s}'.format(natural_language_date, formal_date)

print_todays_date()
convert_date('6 months')
```

The above code generates the following from a MacOSX machine:

```
$ ./parsedatetime_simple.py 
today's date = Wednesday, 2015-05-13
6 months     -> 2015-11-13
$
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this? Not using another library (`dateutil`) or `timedelta`?
building on [vartec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60711/vartec)'s answer I did this and I believe it works:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
six_months_from_today = datetime.date(today.year + (today.month + 6)/12, (today.month + 6) % 12, today.day)
```

I tried using `timedelta`, but because it is counting the days, `365/2` or `6*356/12` does not always translate to 6 months, but rather 182 days. e.g.

```
day = datetime.date(2015, 3, 10)
print day
>>> 2015-03-10

print (day + datetime.timedelta(6*365/12))
>>> 2015-09-08
```

I believe that we usually assume that 6 month's from a certain day will land on the same day of the month but 6 months later (i.e. `2015-03-10` --> `2015-09-10`, Not `2015-09-08`)

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: `day + datetime.timedelta(6*365/12)` won't work always, as some years have 365 days and others have 366 days.

Comment: `day + datetime.timedelta(6*365/12)` is the wrong way

Answer (score 2):

Here's a example which allows the user to decide how to return a date where the day is greater than the number of days in the month.

```
def add_months(date, months, endOfMonthBehaviour='RoundUp'):
    assert endOfMonthBehaviour in ['RoundDown', 'RoundIn', 'RoundOut', 'RoundUp'], \
        'Unknown end of month behaviour'
    year = date.year + (date.month + months - 1) / 12
    month = (date.month + months - 1) % 12 + 1
    day = date.day
    last = monthrange(year, month)[1]
    if day > last:
        if endOfMonthBehaviour == 'RoundDown' or \
            endOfMonthBehaviour == 'RoundOut' and months < 0 or \
            endOfMonthBehaviour == 'RoundIn' and months > 0:
            day = last
        elif endOfMonthBehaviour == 'RoundUp' or \
            endOfMonthBehaviour == 'RoundOut' and months > 0 or \
            endOfMonthBehaviour == 'RoundIn' and months < 0:
            # we don't need to worry about incrementing the year
            # because there will never be a day in December > 31
            month += 1
            day = 1
    return datetime.date(year, month, day)


>>> from calendar import monthrange
>>> import datetime
>>> add_months(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 31), 1)
datetime.date(2016, 3, 1)
>>> add_months(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 31), -2)
datetime.date(2015, 12, 1)
>>> add_months(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 31), -2, 'RoundDown')
datetime.date(2015, 11, 30)
```

Answer (score 2):

given that your datetime variable is called date:

```
date=datetime.datetime(year=date.year+int((date.month+6)/12),
                       month=(date.month+6)%13 + (1 if (date.month + 
                       months>12) else 0), day=date.day)
```

Answer (score 2):

General function to get next date after/before x months.

```
from datetime import date

def after_month(given_date, month):
    yyyy = int(((given_date.year * 12 + given_date.month) + month)/12)
    mm = int(((given_date.year * 12 + given_date.month) + month)%12)

    if mm == 0:
        yyyy -= 1
        mm = 12
    return given_date.replace(year=yyyy, month=mm)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    today = date.today()
    print(today)

    for mm in [-12, -1, 0, 1, 2, 12, 20 ]:
        next_date = after_month(today, mm)
        print(next_date)
```

Comment: This is clearly the best answer.  Simple and effective, without rounding issues.

Answer (score 2):

Im chiming in late, but

check out Ken Reitz Maya module,

https://github.com/kennethreitz/maya

something like this may help you, just change hours=1 to days=1 or years=1

```
>>> from maya import MayaInterval

# Create an event that is one hour long, starting now.
>>> event_start = maya.now()
>>> event_end = event_start.add(hours=1)

>>> event = MayaInterval(start=event_start, end=event_end)
```

Comment: can also use Pendulum module (Maya is based on Pendulum)

https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum

Answer (score 2):

The "python-dateutil" (external extension) is a good solution, but you can do it with build-in Python modules (datetime and datetime)

I made a short and simple code, to solve it (dealing with year, month and day)

(running: Python 3.8.2)

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

# Time to increase (in months)
inc = 12

# Returns mod of the division for 12 (months)
month = ((datetime.now().month + inc) % 12) or 1

# Increase the division by 12 (months), if necessary (+ 12 months increase)
year = datetime.now().year + int((month + inc) / 12)

# (IF YOU DON'T NEED DAYS,CAN REMOVE THE BELOW CODE)
# Returns the same day in new month, or the maximum day of new month
day = min(datetime.now().day,monthrange(year, month)[1])

print("Year: {}, Month: {}, Day: {}".format(year, month, day))
```

Comment: by using "math.floor" instead of "int", decrease functionality would also be supported

Answer (score 2):

I often need last day of month to remain last day of month. To solve that I add one day before calculation and then subtract it again before return.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

# it's a lot faster with a constant day
DAY = timedelta(1)

def add_month(a_date, months):
    "Add months to date and retain last day in month."
    next_day = a_date + DAY
    # calculate new year and month
    m_sum = next_day.month + months - 1
    y = next_day.year + m_sum // 12
    m = m_sum % 12 + 1
    try:
        return date(y, m, next_day.day) - DAY
    except ValueError:
        # on fail return last day in month
        # can't fail on december so I don't bother changing the year
        return date(y, m + 1, 1) - DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to do this using **datetime** and **MonthDelta**

```
pip install MonthDelta
```

Then

```py
from datetime import datetime
from monthdelta import monthdelta

# Date and time today, now
now        = datetime.now()

# Date next six months from now
six_months = now + monthdelta(6)

print( now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") )
print( six_months.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") )
```

```
>>> 2023-06-11
>>> 2023-12-11
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It moves the correct number of months and years but ignores days (which was what I needed in my situation).

```
import datetime

month_dt = 4
today = datetime.date.today()
y,m = today.year, today.month
m += month_dt-1
year_dt = m//12
new_month = m%12
new_date = datetime.date(y+year_dt, new_month+1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to change year and month but keep day:

```
def replace_month_year(date1, year2, month2):
    try:
        date2 = date1.replace(month = month2, year = year2)
    except:
        date2 = datetime.date(year2, month2 + 1, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return date2
```

You should write:

```
new_year = my_date.year + (my_date.month + 6) / 12
new_month = (my_date.month + 6) % 12
new_date = replace_month_year(my_date, new_year, new_month)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be safer to do something like this instead of manually adding days:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()

def addMonths(dt, months = 0):
    new_month = months + dt.month
    year_inc = 0
    if new_month>12:
        year_inc +=1
        new_month -=12
    return dt.replace(month = new_month, year = dt.year+year_inc)

newdate = addMonths(today, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
moths2add = 6
now = datetime.now()
current_year = now.year
current_month = now.month
#count days in months you want to add using calendar module
days = sum(
  [calendar.monthrange(current_year, elem)[1] for elem in range(current_month, current_month + moths)]
    )
print now + days
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: calculate sum of days in month for next n month and add result to current date.

```
import calendar
import datetime

def date_from_now(months):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()

    month = today.month
    year = today.year
    sum_days = 0

    for i in range(int(months)):
        month += 1

        if month == 13:
            month = 1
            year += 1

        sum_days += calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]

    return datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(sum_days)

print(date_from_now(12)) # if to day is 2017-01-01, output: 2019-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `replace()` method and write this recursive function. the `dt` is a `datetime.datetime` object:

```
def month_timedelta(dt, m):
    y = m // 12
    dm = m % 12
    if y == 0:
        if dt.month + m <= 12:
            return dt.replace(month = dt.month + m)
        else:
            dy = (dt.month + m) // 12
            ndt = dt.replace(year=dt.year + dy)
            return ndt.replace(month=(ndt.month + m) % 12)
    else:
        return month_timedelta(dt.replace(year=dt.year + y),dm)
```

Answer (score 0):

My implementation based on taleinat's answer:

```py
import datetime
import calendar

def add_months(orig_date, month_count = 1):
    while month_count > 12:
        month_count -= 12
        orig_date = add_months(orig_date, 12)
    new_year = orig_date.year
    new_month = orig_date.month + month_count
    # note: in datetime.date, months go from 1 to 12
    if new_month > 12:
        new_year += 1
        new_month -= 12

    last_day_of_month = calendar.monthrange(new_year, new_month)[1]
    new_day = min(orig_date.day, last_day_of_month)

    return orig_date.replace(year=new_year, month=new_month, day=new_day)
```

With this function you can add as many months as you'd like.

```
from datetime import date
dt = date(2021, 1, 31)

print(add_months(dt, 49))
```

returns
`2025-02-28`

Answer (score 0):

I know that there are many answers to this question already, but using `collections.deque` and then the `rotate()` method, a function can be made that takes a `datetime` object as the input and then outputs a new `datetime` object that is one "business month" later than the current one. If the day of the month does not exist in the next month, then it subtracts one until it arrives on a valid day of the month and then returns that object.

```py
import collections
import datetime

def next_month(dt: datetime.datetime):
    month_list = list(range(1, 12 + 1))
    months = collections.deque(month_list)
    while True:
        this_month = list(months)[0]
        if dt.month == this_month:
            break
        months.rotate(-1)
    months.rotate(-1)
    month_plus = list(months)[0]
    for i in range(4):
        try:
            return dt.replace(month=month_plus, day=dt.day - i)
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

The same end result can be done using `itertools.cycle`.

```py
import datetime
import itertools

def next_month(dt: datetime.datetime):
    month_list = list(range(1, 12 + 1))
    month = itertools.cycle(month_list)
    while True:
        if next(month) == dt.month:
            break
    month_plus = next(month)
    for i in range(4):
        try:
            return dt.replace(month=month_plus, day=dt.day - i)
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

Answer (score -1):

My modification to Tony Diep's answer, possibly marginally more elegant (Python 2 of course, matching the date of the question & original answers, for Python 3 modify as necessary, including `/` to `//` at least):

```
def add_months(date, months):
    month = date.month + months - 1
    year = date.year + (month / 12)
    month = (month % 12) + 1
    day = date.day
    while (day > 0):
        try:
            new_date = date.replace(year=year, month=month, day=day)
            break
        except:
            day = day - 1    
    return new_date
```

adds months according to a 'business needs' interpretation that dates mapping beyond the end of the month, should map to the end of the month rather than into the following month.

Answer (score -1):

In this function, n can be positive or negative.

```
def addmonth(d, n):
    n += 1
    dd = datetime.date(d.year + n/12, d.month + n%12, 1)-datetime.timedelta(1)
    return datetime.date(dd.year, dd.month, min(d.day, dd.day))
```

Answer (score -1):

We probably should use dateutil.relativedelta

however for academic interest I will just add that before I discovered it I was goint to use this:

try:
   vexpDt = K.today.replace(K.today.year + (K.today.month+6)//12, (K.today.month+5)%12+1, K.today.day)
except:
   vexpDt = K.today.replace(K.today.year + (K.today.month+6)//12, (K.today.month+6)%12+1, 1) - timedelta(days = 1)

it seems quite simple but still catches all the issues like 29,30,31

it also works for - 6 mths by doing -timedelta

nb - don't be confused by K.today its just a variable in my program

Answer (score -1):

```
    def addDay(date, number):
        for i in range(number)
            #try to add a day
            try:
                date = date.replace(day = date.day + 1)
            #in case it's impossible ex:january 32nd add a month and restart at day 1
            except:
                #add month part
                try:
                    date = date.replace(month = date.month +1, day = 1)
                except:
                    date = date.replace(year = date.year +1, month = 1, day = 1)
```

For everyone still reading this post. I think this code is way clearer, especially compared to code using modulo(%).

Sorry for any grammatical error, english is so not my main language

Answer (score -1):

This is what I do when I need to add months or years and don't want to import more libraries.

```
import datetime
__author__ = 'Daniel Margarido'


# Check if the int given year is a leap year
# return true if leap year or false otherwise
def is_leap_year(year):
    if (year % 4) == 0:
        if (year % 100) == 0:
            if (year % 400) == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False


THIRTY_DAYS_MONTHS = [4, 6, 9, 11]
THIRTYONE_DAYS_MONTHS = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]

# Inputs -> month, year Booth integers
# Return the number of days of the given month
def get_month_days(month, year):
    if month in THIRTY_DAYS_MONTHS:   # April, June, September, November
        return 30
    elif month in THIRTYONE_DAYS_MONTHS:   # January, March, May, July, August, October, December
        return 31
    else:   # February
        if is_leap_year(year):
            return 29
        else:
            return 28

# Checks the month of the given date
# Selects the number of days it needs to add one month
# return the date with one month added
def add_month(date):
    current_month_days = get_month_days(date.month, date.year)
    next_month_days = get_month_days(date.month + 1, date.year)

    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=current_month_days)
    if date.day > next_month_days:
        delta = delta - datetime.timedelta(days=(date.day - next_month_days) - 1)

    return date + delta


def add_year(date):
    if is_leap_year(date.year):
        delta = datetime.timedelta(days=366)
    else:
        delta = datetime.timedelta(days=365)

    return date + delta


# Validates if the expected_value is equal to the given value
def test_equal(expected_value, value):
    if expected_value == value:
        print "Test Passed"
        return True

    print "Test Failed : " + str(expected_value) + " is not equal to " str(value)
    return False

# Test leap year
print "---------- Test leap year ----------"
test_equal(True, is_leap_year(2012))
test_equal(True, is_leap_year(2000))
test_equal(False, is_leap_year(1900))
test_equal(False, is_leap_year(2002))
test_equal(False, is_leap_year(2100))
test_equal(True, is_leap_year(2400))
test_equal(True, is_leap_year(2016))

# Test add month
print "---------- Test add month ----------"
test_equal(datetime.date(2016, 2, 1), add_month(datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)))
test_equal(datetime.date(2016, 6, 16), add_month(datetime.date(2016, 5, 16)))
test_equal(datetime.date(2016, 3, 15), add_month(datetime.date(2016, 2, 15)))
test_equal(datetime.date(2017, 1, 12), add_month(datetime.date(2016, 12, 12)))
test_equal(datetime.date(2016, 3, 1), add_month(datetime.date(2016, 1, 31)))
test_equal(datetime.date(2015, 3, 1), add_month(datetime.date(2015, 1, 31)))
test_equal(datetime.date(2016, 3, 1), add_month(datetime.date(2016, 1, 30)))
test_equal(datetime.date(2016, 4, 30), add_month(datetime.date(2016, 3, 30)))
test_equal(datetime.date(2016, 5, 1), add_month(datetime.date(2016, 3, 31)))

# Test add year
print "---------- Test add year ----------"
test_equal(datetime.date(2016, 2, 2), add_year(datetime.date(2015, 2, 2)))
test_equal(datetime.date(2001, 2, 2), add_year(datetime.date(2000, 2, 2)))
test_equal(datetime.date(2100, 2, 2), add_year(datetime.date(2099, 2, 2)))
test_equal(datetime.date(2101, 2, 2), add_year(datetime.date(2100, 2, 2)))
test_equal(datetime.date(2401, 2, 2), add_year(datetime.date(2400, 2, 2)))
```

Just create a datetime.date() object, call add_month(date) to add a month and add_year(date) to add a year.

Comment: ``add_month(datetime(2015, 1, 31))`` would yield ``2015-03-03`` which is probably not what people would expect for ``adding one month``.

Comment: Fixed, now 2015-03-01 would be returned instead of 2015-03-03

Answer (score -1):

Using below given function you can get date after/before x months.

```
from datetime import date

def next_month(given_date, month):
    yyyy = int(((given_date.year * 12 + given_date.month) + month)/12)
    mm = int(((given_date.year * 12 + given_date.month) + month)%12)

    if mm == 0:
        yyyy -= 1
        mm = 12
    return given_date.replace(year=yyyy, month=mm)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    today = date.today()
    print(today)

    for mm in [-12, -1, 0, 1, 2, 12, 20 ]:
        next_date = next_month(today, mm)
        print(next_date)
```

Comment: This answer is an exact duplicate of an answer you posted 8 minutes earlier to this same question.  Please delete this redundant answer.

Answer (score -1):

I could not find an exact solution to this question so i'll post my solution in case it may be of any help using stantard Calendar and datetime libs. this works for add and substract months, and accounts for month-end rolls and cases where the final month has less days than the initial one. I also have a more generalized solution if you are looking for more complex manipulation, it adds regular intervals (days, months, years, quarters, semeters, etc) like: '1m', '-9m', '-1.5y', '-3q', '1s' etc.

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import monthrange
def date_bump_months(start_date, months):
    """
    bumps months back and forth. 
    --> if initial date is end-of-month, i will move to corresponding month-end
    --> ir inital date.day is greater than end of month of final date, it casts it to momth-end
    """
    signbit = -1 if months < 0 else 1
    d_year, d_month = divmod(abs(months),12)    
    end_year = start_date.year + d_year*signbit 
    end_month = 0
    if signbit ==-1:            
        if d_month < start_date.month:
            end_month = start_date.month - d_month
        else:
            end_year -=1
            end_month = 12 - (d_month - start_date.month)
    else:
        end_month +=start_date.month
        if end_month  > 12:
            end_year +=1
            end_month -=12
    # check if we are running end-of-month dates
    eom_run = monthrange(start_date.year, start_date.month)[1]==start_date.day
    eom_month = monthrange((end_year), (end_month))[1]
    if eom_run:
        end_day = eom_month 
    else:
        end_day = min(start_date.day, eom_month )    
    return date(end_year, end_month, end_day)
```

Answer (score -6):

Use the python datetime module to add a timedelta of six months to datetime.today() .

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

You will of course have to solve the issue raised by Johannes Weiß-- what *do* you mean by 6 months?

Comment: timedelta doesn't support months and so sidesteps the possible answers to the question "how many days in 6-month?"

Eef's code will set a review date so I would suggest one could consider setting the timedelta using days (6*30).

If the period represents clients' access to a product/service then a business definition may be required/preferred.