# Parse a string with a date to a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

How can I parse a string like "01-Jan-1995" to a Python `datetime` object?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On the whole you'd parse date and time strings with the `strptime` functions in `time` or `datetime` modules. Your example could be parsed with:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("01-Jan-1995", "%d-%b-%Y")
```

Note that parsing month names is locale-dependent. [This table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) shows the directives for parsing various formats of dates and times.

Answer (score 10):

[dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) can parse this sort of format without you even having to define custom date formats. Just install it with:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Then use it:

```
import dateutil.parser
dateutil.parser.parse('01-Jan-1995').date()
```

Comment: +1 for python-dateutil. It can even parse datestrings without you having to tell it the format.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to parse natural language date and time strings, consider [parsedatetime](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime) (and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495487/is-there-any-python-library-for-parsing-dates-and-times-from-a-natural-language/1495548#1495548)).