# Parse date string and change format

Tags: python, date, datetime, strptime, strftime

I have a date string with the format 'Mon Feb 15 2010'.  I want to change the format to '15/02/2010'.  How can I do this?

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+parse+date.  Exact duplicate of thise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713594/parsing-dates-and-times-from-strings-using-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse a string with a date to a datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713594/parse-a-string-with-a-date-to-a-datetime-object)

Answer (score 282, accepted):

The [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module could help you with that:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date_string, input_format).strftime(output_format)
```

For the specific example, you could do:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('Mon Feb 15 2010', '%a %b %d %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'15/02/2010'
```

Learn more about different formats [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Comment: `format1` needs to be a string to express the input date string's format. `format2` is the target string format to output.

Comment: Tutorial for strptime and its format string: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm

Comment: `strptime` and `strftime` are really powerful functions. It's weird I couldn't find them in the python docs

Answer (score 114):

You can install the [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library.  Its [`parse`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c) function can figure out what format a string is in without having to specify the format like you do with `datetime.strptime`.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dt = parse('Mon Feb 15 2010')
print(dt)
# datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 15, 0, 0)
print(dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
# 15/02/2010
```

Comment: dateutil.parse is a better alternative if the exact format of a legal ISO string is unknown. ISO may or may not contain microseconds. It may or may not contain trailing "Z". datetime.strptime is not flexible enough to accomodate for that.

Comment: Pase Date should be used with care. parse('12.07.2017') returns datetime(2017, 12, 7, ..) but parse('13.07.2017') returns .datetime(2017, 7, 13, ...)

Comment: In `python 3.x` needs to install `python-dateutil`
`pip install python-dateutil`

Comment: Just an update from Michael Kariv, parse provides a param `dayfirst` that will be used to deferentiate between YDM and YMD dates [parse docs](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#:~:text=dayfirst%20%E2%80%93%20Whether%20to,defaults%20to%20False).)

Answer (score 38):

Convert a string to a datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime
s = "2016-03-26T09:25:55.000Z"
f = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
out = datetime.strptime(s, f)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
2016-03-26 09:25:55
```

Comment: This is not according to the format he asked, which had a month string "Feb" in it.

Comment: @ShahirAnsari you can change the format as you like refer "https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html"

Answer (score 27):

```
>>> from_date="Mon Feb 15 2010"
>>> import time                
>>> conv=time.strptime(from_date,"%a %b %d %Y")
>>> time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y",conv)
'15/02/2010'
```

Answer (score 17):

As this question comes often, here is the simple explanation.

`datetime` or `time` module has two important functions.

- **strftime** - creates a string representation of date or time from a datetime or time object.
- **strptime** - creates a datetime or time object from a string.

In both cases, we need a formating string. It is the representation that tells how the date or time is formatted in your string.

Now lets assume we have a date object.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime(2010, 2, 15)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 15, 0, 0)
```

If we want to create a string from this date in the format `'Mon Feb 15 2010'`

```
>>> s = d.strftime('%a %b %d %y')
>>> print s
Mon Feb 15 10
```

Lets assume we want to convert this `s` again to a `datetime` object.

```
>>> new_date = datetime.strptime(s, '%a %b %d %y')
>>> print new_date
2010-02-15 00:00:00
```

Refer [This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) document all formatting directives regarding datetime.

Answer (score 4):

@codeling and @user1767754 : The following two lines will work. I saw no one posted the complete solution for the example problem that was asked. Hopefully this is enough explanation.

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.strptime("Mon Feb 15 2010", "%a %b %d %Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print(x)
```

Output:

```
15/02/2010
```

Answer (score 3):

You may achieve this using pandas as well:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime('Mon Feb 15 2010', format='%a %b %d %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Output:

```
'15/02/2010'
```

You may apply pandas approach for different datatypes as:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def reformat_date(date_string, old_format, new_format):
    return pd.to_datetime(date_string, format=old_format, errors='ignore').strftime(new_format)

date_string = 'Mon Feb 15 2010'
date_list = ['Mon Feb 15 2010', 'Wed Feb 17 2010']
date_array = np.array(date_list)
date_series = pd.Series(date_list)

old_format = '%a %b %d %Y'
new_format = '%d/%m/%Y'

print(reformat_date(date_string, old_format, new_format))
print(reformat_date(date_list, old_format, new_format).values)
print(reformat_date(date_array, old_format, new_format).values)
print(date_series.apply(lambda x: reformat_date(x, old_format, new_format)).values)
```

Output:

```
15/02/2010
['15/02/2010' '17/02/2010']
['15/02/2010' '17/02/2010']
['15/02/2010' '17/02/2010']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completion: when parsing a date using `strptime()` and the date contains the *name* of a day, month, etc, be aware that you have to account for the locale.

It's mentioned as a footnote in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) as well.

As an example:

```
import locale
print(locale.getlocale())

>> ('nl_BE', 'ISO8859-1')

from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('6-Mar-2016', '%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

>> ValueError: time data '6-Mar-2016' does not match format '%d-%b-%Y'

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
datetime.strptime('6-Mar-2016', '%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

>> '2016-03-06'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the strptime() and strftime() functions in the *[datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)* library.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Examples: *[3. Dates and Times](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/datesandtimes.html)*

Comment: for the error above nimmyliji you should have done
datetime.datetime.strptime("Mon Feb 15 2010", "%a %b %d %Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
it gives '15/02/2010'

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to define the input date format then, Install dateparser (pip install dateparser) and,

```
from dateparser import parse
parse("Mon Feb 15 2010").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```