# Displaying date from string in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse date and format it using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-and-format-it-using-python)

I have the following string in python:

```
2011-05-25T02:11:04Z
```

How can I convert it to

```
May, 25th 2:11
```

Comment: You can also use [isodate](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/isodate/) since the string is a valid [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string.

Answer (score 2):

`datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-05-25T02:11:04Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')` gives you a `datetime.datetime` object with the correct date / time.