# Parsing the string to Dates in python

Tags: python, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse date and format it using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-and-format-it-using-python)

I'm very new to Python. I have the following two strings :

```
Mon, 29 Oct 2012 13:07:07 GMT
2012-10-29 12:57:08
```

I wish there could be any date parsing lib available in python which does parse the above two strings to something like this:

```
2012-10-29 12:57:08
```

So that I can compare them. Note that the comparison should be able to produce the result like integer comparison. Like `1` is less than `2`, so the same way `2012-10-29 12:57:08` is less than `2012-10-29 13:57:08`

Are there any easy to do so in python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-and-format-it-using-python . That is a duplicate of this question, that in turn identifies multiple other duplicates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`dateutil` module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) for general date parsing:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('Mon, 29 Oct 2012 13:07:07 GMT')
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 29, 13, 7, 7, tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> parse('2012-10-29 12:57:08')
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 29, 12, 57, 8)
```

`datetime.datetime` objects can be compared in various ways.

If you know the exact format of each date string to be parsed, you can also do the parsing more explicitly using the [`datetime.datetime.strptime()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('Mon, 29 Oct 2012 13:07:07 GMT', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 29, 13, 7, 7)
```

Note however that that method *ignores* timezones!

Comment: +1 That works. But how do I compare the two result in order to find which one is smaller or greater?

Comment: @GroovyUser: Like you would other values: `dt1 < dt2`, etc. Note that you may want to *remove* the timezone and/or cast everything to UTC first (`dt1.astimezone(datutil.tz.tzutc())` for datetime objects with a timezone, `dt2.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzutc())` for those without, or use the `default` keyword to `parse` to give all parsed datetime objects a timezone even if the string is missing timezone info. Removing a timezone is done with `.replace(tzinfo=None)`).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [`time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) can convert the text to date representations.  From there you can use [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to print it how you like.

```
>>> a = '2012-10-29 12:57:08'
>>> time.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=29, tm_hour=12, tm_min=57, tm_sec=8, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=303, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> b = 'Mon, 29 Oct 2012 13:07:07 GMT'
>>> time.strptime(b, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=29, tm_hour=13, tm_min=7, tm_sec=7, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=303, tm_isdst=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `datetime` module in python, with its `strptime` function (string parse), can do that.

For example, you can use the function like this:

```
somestring = '2004-03-13T03:00:00Z'
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(somestring, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Docs [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).