# How to save the date format and compare it when time changes in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have to read data from a file. the file is like this.

```
CIRCUITNAME=CIRCUIT1
00.12 12/20 2.3 23.6
00.12 12/20 2.3 23.6
00.42 12/20 2.2 23.3
00.42 12/20 2.2 23.3
00.42 12/20 2.2 23.3
01.12 12/20 2.2 23.1
01.12 12/20 2.2 23.1
```

Now, I have coded a function which reads this and return a corresponding numpy array for every column.

```
def load_ci(filepath):
 fileObj=open(filepath, 'r')
 time_1=[]
 time_2=[]
 date_count=[]
 t=0
 ti=0
 d=""
 #da=0
 loadCurrent_1=[]
 surfaceTemp_1=[]
 loadCurrent_2=[]
 surfaceTemp_2=[]
 ambient=[]
 read=0
 for line in fileObj:
    if not line.strip():
        continue    
    if read==1:
        if '[AMBIENT]' in line:
            read=3
            continue
        elif  'CIRCUITNAME=CIRCUIT2' in line: read=2
        else:
            if line!='\n' and '[CIRCUIT2]' not in line:
                point=line.split(' ')                    
                date_count.append(point[1])
                t=(float(point[0]))
                ti=int(t)*3600+(t-int(t))*60*100
                time_1.append(ti)
                loadCurrent_1.append(float(point[2]))
                surfaceTemp_1.append(float(point[3]))
    if read==2:
        if '[AMBIENT]' in line:
            read=3
            continue
        elif  'CIRCUITNAME=CIRCUIT2' in line: read=2
        else:
            if line!='\n' and '[CIRCUIT2]' not in line:
                point=line.split(' ')
                t=(float(point[0]))
                ti=int(t)*3600+(t-int(t))*60*100
                time_2.append(ti)
                loadCurrent_2.append(float(point[2]))
                surfaceTemp_2.append(float(point[3]))
    if read==3:
        if line!='\n':
            point=line.split(' ')
            ambient.append(float(point[2]))
    if 'CIRCUITNAME=CIRCUIT1' in line: read=1
return  np.array(loadCurrent_1), np.array(surfaceTemp_1),np.array(loadCurrent_2),np.array(surfaceTemp_2),np.array(ambient),np.array(time_1),np.array(time_2),np.array(date_count)
```

a= load_ci("2_Horizontal_Drilling_800mm_20121221_001235.ci")
   print a

But, I could not able to save the month-date as floats because of '/' in between months and dates. I need to save the month-date like '12.05' which means 12th of May. Then when the next day comes '12.05' becomes '12.06' and I have to save the time values accordingly by adding hours for a new day. But I could not able to save my date as a float value. Please give me some suggestions or any other way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use datetime as it will make it a lot easier to iterate over days etc. and switch between date formats:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Having a look there might help to get started:

[Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-and-format-it-using-python)

You first need to parse your dates, then you can play with them as you wish and finally get them back as string or float

Comment: I used the program like this to save my date and time and appended this for future comparison with the previous values to an array. But it doesn't work.                                             date_count=[]                           d=datetime.datetime.strptime(point[0]+" "+point[1],'%H.%M %d/%m') date_count.append(d)

Comment: My guess is your problem comes from the fact that you inversed day and month. You should be ok with this: `date_test = datetime.datetime.strptime("01.12 12/20", "%H.%M %m/%d")`. You can then add a day like this: `date_test + datetime.timedelta(days=1)`. Be cautious: if you don't provide a year.. as you can see it is assumed the date is in 1900... it might be an issue when adding 1 day on the 30th of the month. If you don't mind, it would best to provide the year: `datetime.datetime.strptime("01.12 12/20/2012", "%H.%M %m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: Btw, to get the date back in original format as string after having added one day to the datetime object: `date_test_2 = date_test + datetime.timedelta(days=1)` then `date_test_2.strftime("%H.%M %m/%d")`

Comment: Yes you are right. I have already solved my problem before watching your answer. Thanks anyway for your valuable comments

Comment: Great, you may consider marking the answer as accepted if it indeed helped and the problem is solved :)