# Time difference in python

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime
t=str(datetime.now())
```

I store this time in a mysql table in varchar format. Now I want to retrieve this time from mysql table and subtract it from the current time.
How do I do it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: Why don't you use the proper MySQL type for a datetime? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

That depends, you're storing it as a varchar, so presumably you need to get it back into a datetime? (something like sqlalchemy would do this for you)

You can use [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert your string (varchar) back to a datetime object.

Then

```
datetime.now() - retrieved_time
```

will give you a [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object

**edit**: help as requested

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> t = datetime.now()
>>> print t
2014-04-16 08:33:22.309991
```

that's the format you should be storing in your db

```
>>> stored_t = datetime.strptime('2014-04-10 08:32:00.934079', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") # You should be getting this from your db
>>> print stored_t
2014-04-10 08:32:00.934079
>>> td = t - stored_t
>>> print td
6 days, 0:01:21.375912
```

Comment: from datetime import datetime
t=str(datetime.now())
print(t)

date_object = datetime.strptime("t", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(date_object)
Could you help me with this code?

Answer (score 0):

This falls into two separate tasks:

- How to parse date from string [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-and-format-it-using-python).
- How to use mysql from python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python/622308)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,
Here is [demo](http://codepad.org/nudYw41Q)

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now=datetime.now()
>>> d1='2014-4-14' #get this from database.
>>> d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
>>> (now-d1).days
```

Output:

```
1
```