# Pythonic way to get datetime from string without leading zero

Tags: python, datetime

Pythonic way to get datetime from a string without leading zeroes?

e.g. no leading zero for Hour (typical case)

```
'Date: Jul 10, 2014 4:41:28 PM'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: same here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-and-format-it-using-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) would handle it from out-of-the-box (`fuzzy` helps to ignore unrelated parts of the string):

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> s = "Date: Jul 10, 2014 4:41:28 PM"
>>> parser.parse(s, fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 10, 16, 41, 28)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `dateutil`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, 'Date: %b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p')
>>> d.hour
16
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 10, 16, 41, 28)
```