# tuples using time and date with tuples

Tags: python-3.x

i need to use spyder to convert time and date using tuples.

it is like that  `def problem3_3(month, day, year)`.Write a function that will convert a date from one format to another.

Specifically, `06/10/2016` should convert to `June 17, 2016`.  Actually, you
will input the 6, the 17, and the 2016 as separate integers `(numbers)` and
the function will assemble and print the date as June 17, 2016.

I suggest that you create a `tuple months = ("January", "February", "March", ...)` to 
store the names of the months. 
 Then it is easy to access the name February
as `months[1]` and so on..
please help. thanks

Comment: thanks sir, but can i concatenate and how, because it gives me this error(TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse date string and change format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Answer (score 0):

```
def problem3_3(month, day, year):
""" Takes date of form mm/dd/yyyy and writes it in form June 17, 2016 
    Example3_3: problem3_3(6, 17, 2016) gives June 17, 2016 """
months=("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

for month in months:

    #print (month[5] +" "+str(day)+", "+str(year))
    print (months[month-1] +" "+ str(day)+", "+ str(year))
```