# My date in being transformed to UTC?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, formatting, utc

I got this function below which helps me to change a date format from one to another:

```
def change_time_format(self, date_string, input_format, output_format):

    if date_string == None:
        return None

    try:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, input_format)
        timestamp = calendar.timegm(date.timetuple())
        new_formatted_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime(output_format)
        return new_formatted_date
    except Exception as E:
        print E
        return None
```

And when i'm calling it like this:

```
dtu.change_time_format('2017-01-01 12:34:56', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%d%m%Y %H%M%S')
```

I'm getting the input as:'01012017 153456' which is wrong and needs to be: '01012017 123456', there is a difference of 3 hours for some reason.

I can't find how to fix it, I searched for several ways over the web and I couldn't find nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse date string and change format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format):

```
return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, input_format).strftime(output_format)
```