# How can I parse this data to specified format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, date, dataframe

I am trying to parse data from `2018-03-31 15:58` to `2018-03-31T15:58:00Z`. Is it possible to achieve this using dataframe or another library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `datetime` module

```
import datetime
s = "2018-03-31 15:58"
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(s , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
```

**Output:**

```
2018-03-31T15:58:00Z
```

Or using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
s = "2018-03-31 15:58"
print(pd.to_datetime(s).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted to achieve.