# Python remove some alphabet from a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python newb here. I have a string as 'July 27, 2019'
I want output as 'Jul. 27, 2019'
Please let me know how can I achieve the same.

Comment: use replace function in strings.

Comment: Consider this `datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format1).strftime(format2)`

Comment: [`strftime()` and `strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Also, guys stop down voting him, he is obviously new... Instead let's explain to him what he should do in the future.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Well, that's what [these links](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) are for. I downvoted because there's no research, no code, and only a statement of "I need X."

Comment: @JoshDetwiler Down-voting him is entirely justifed since you at least provided him with a reason, that's what I meant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `datetime` module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
d = 'July 27, 2019'
print( datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%B %d, %Y").strftime("%b. %d, %Y") )
```

**Output:**

```
Jul. 27, 2019
```

- `strptime` to convert string to datetime object.
- `strftime` to convert the datetime object to your required format.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh,
Thanks for above answer.
If my d = 'Aug. 27, 2019', then also above logic will work??
Or it will not work?? Please let me know
Sometimes month is displayed as "July" or sometimes as "Aug."
I want output as "First 3 chars of month followed by a dot"
E.g. October 27, 2019 will be shown as "Oct. 27, 2019"
i.e. whenever month name length exceeds 3, it should be reduced to 3 and followed by a dot.