# How do you autofill your csv name depending on variable in sql query

Tags: python, sql, csv

I have an SQL query in my python script that starts with the following query:

```
query = """
DECLARE @StartDate AS Date 
SET @StartDate = '2018-10-31'

SELECT  ...
FROM ...
...
"""
```

At the end of my python script im creating two csv files as such:

```
df.to_csv('C:/path/a_05-11-18.csv', sep=",",
                       encoding='utf-8', index=False)
df2.to_csv('C:/path/b_05-11-18.csv',
                           sep=",", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I would like that when I change the date, in the

> SET @StartDate = '2018-11-05'

that my dates in my file name changes accordingly.

Comment: What is a and b in your file names?

Comment: How have you made the query dynamic? Presumably you have the date stored in some variable, just use `.format()`

Comment: sure but how is it applied?

Comment: You need to tell us exactly which part you'd like to change based on the date. Also if you have a certain format of the date in mind.

Comment: the format should be the same as described in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the date in a variable as string.

Change it to a desired format if you need to. For that, see here [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format).

Now let's say the the new date string is stored in the variable `modified_date`.

When you're writing the csv file, the first argument of the `to_csv` function should look like this: `'C:/path/part_of_filename_etc' + modified_date + '.csv'`