# what is django datetime field format

Tags: python, django, datetime

I send django datetime field data to client in string type

my question is how i can convert this string to python datetime?

my datetime is:
`"2019-07-22T10:01:40.876487+04:30"`

I want to do something like this:

```py
datatime.datetime('2019-07-22T10:01:40.876487+04:30', '<django default datetime format>')
```

and I expect to have:

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

WHAT IS DJANGO DEFAULT DATETIME FORMAT?

OR HOW I CAN CONVERT THIS STRING TO DATETIME?

Comment: probably this will help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_FORMAT

Comment: For the record, that datetime format is the gold standard of datetime formats, ISO8601.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [django's dateparse library](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/2.2/_modules/django/utils/dateparse/), which is fairly comprehensive and robust wrt [the iso 8601 formats](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime

datetime_obj = parse_datetime('2019-07-22T10:01:40.876487+04:30')
# datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 22, 10, 1, 40, 876487, tzinfo=<django.utils.timezone.FixedOffset object at 0x7f9251844f98>)
```