# How to convert date to mysql date format in python scrapy

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

Basically I am getting  Aug 11, 2017 type of date in scrapy.
How to convert it to mysql date format like 2017-08-11 00:00:00 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your time string directly in mysql .
Like

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (CAST(STR_TO_DATE('Aug 11, 2017','%b %d,%Y') as DATETIME));;
```

example

```
CAST(STR_TO_DATE('Aug 11, 2017','%b %d,%Y') as DATETIME)
2017-08-11 00:00:00
```

It5 uses [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to get a mysql date and then uses [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html) to get a DATETIME.

you could use instead of CAST also [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)