# Python: Change date list from DDMM to DD-MM

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of dates, i.e.:

```
dates = 1104, 1504, 1704, 2204
```

How do I transform it to

```
dates = 11-04, 15-04, 17-04, 22-04
```

with a for loop?

I know how to add more characters to the end of each element. Just not sure how to add it to the middle. I am using python 3.x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Comment: I dont think parsing is needed simple string slicing will do

Comment: If such line is a real code, what datatype are `dates` elements? `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `datetime` for this simple task.

You can use string slicing here to return of tuple of strings in `"DD-MM"` format. You can slice everything up until the 2nd character(but not including) with `[:2]`, and everything after the second character with `[2:]`. Then you can just put a dash `"-"` between the slices.

```
>>> dates = 1104, 1504, 1704, 2204
>>> tuple(f"{x[:2]}-{x[2:]}" for x in map(str, dates))
('11-04', '15-04', '17-04', '22-04')
```

I returned a `tuple` since `dates` is that type. I also converted the integers from `dates` to `str` using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), since you can't slice integers. You can also use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to format the slices into `"DD-MM"` format.

Also I'm assuming you wanted your expected output to be a tuple of strings, since `dates = 11-04, 15-04, 17-04, 22-04` alone would be invalid.

### Update

If you want to extract the dates from `input()`, you pass in input delimited by `","` to split into a list of strings:

```
>>> dates = input()
1104, 1504, 1704, 2204
>>> dates
'1104, 1504, 1704, 2204'
>>> tuple(f"{x[:2]}-{x[2:]}" for x in map(str.strip, dates.split(",")))
('11-04', '15-04', '17-04', '22-04')
```

Which also strips leftover whitespace with [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), since inputs could possibly be `1104, 1504, 1704, 2204`, `1104,1504,1704,2204`, `1104, 1504,1704, 2204` etc. Its much easier to just split on `","`, then strip the whitespace afterwards.

Comment: how would you make it work if I draw the dates with input()?

Comment: @user2803490 Added a way to do it with `input()`.

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to convert all of the dates to strings (if they already are strings, you can skip this step):

```py
dates = [1104, 1504, 1704, 2204]
dates = list(map(str, dates))
```

You could also iterate through the dates list and make them each into strings individually but this way does it all in one go.

Next you have to iterate through the list and add a hyphen in the middle of each date string, and then append the new string to a list. You insert the hyphen by separating the string and then making a new string.

```py
datesSeparated = []
for i in dates:
    date = i[:2] + "-" + i[2:]
    datesSeparated.append(date)
```

You could also do this using a list comprehension if that's more your style:

```py
datesSeparated = [i[:2] + "-" + i[2:] for i in dates]
```

Comment: This is very good, thank you. But if I try to input the dates with input, I get something like choose dates: 1104, 1504
['1-', '1-', '0-', '4-', ',-', ' -', '1-', '5-', '0-', '4-']

Comment: Since `map(str, dates)` will give you a generator, you don't need to cast `list()` when iterating it.

Comment: @RoadRunner I didnt know that, thanks for telling me

Answer (score 2):

Slicing in a readable way

```
dates = ["1104", "1504", "1704", "2204"]
new_dates = [date[:2] + "-" + date[2:] for date in dates]
print(new_dates)
```

> ['11-04', '15-04', '17-04', '22-04']