# Format a pattern string to display in desired format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I do have a date and time format printed in '2020-05-06T15:16:24+05:30' which I would like to display in python in the format of YYYY-MMM-DD HH:MM:SS. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Answer (score 1):

You have an ISO8601 datetime; yse the `datetime` module to parse a `datetime` object out of it, then format as required.

Note the timezone information is "hidden" in your desired formatting, but exists in that `tzinfo` property.

```
>>> s = '2020-05-06T15:16:24+05:30'
>>> import datetime
>>> t = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(s)
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 6, 15, 16, 24, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=19800)))
>>> t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2020-05-06 15:16:24'
>>>
```

Comment: I do get this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    t = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(s)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'

Comment: `fromisoformat` was added in Python 3.7. If you have an older Python, you'll need the iso8601 module's `parse_date` function: https://pypi.org/project/iso8601/