# Parsing and rewriting a date-time string

Tags: python, string, datetime, parsing

I have got a string of time data: "2019-08-02 18:18:06.02887" and I am trying to rewrite it as another string "EV190802_181802" in another file.

What I am trying now is splitting the string into lists and reconstructing another string by those lists:

```
hello=data.split(' ')
date=hello[0]
time=hello[1]
world=hello[0].split('-')
stack=time.split('.')
overflow=stack[0].split(':')
print('EV' + world[0] + world[1] + world[2] + '_' + overflow[0] + overflow[1] + overflow[2])
```

However, I have no idea how to remove 20 in 2019/world[0]. Is there any way I could remove '20'?

If there are alternative methods to rewrite the string, welcome to suggest as well.

Comment: Just to be sure: Is it "EV190802_181802" or "EV190802_181806" (with "06" at the end?)

Comment: That was a typo. Sorry for that.

Comment: Sorry for duplication of the question. Anyway, thanks for the answers, guys. I am not sure should I delete the question as some people here post answers different from another one's: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another way to solve the problem,

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> 
>>> format_ = datetime.strptime("2019-08-02 18:18:06.02887", 
...                             "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
>>> 
>>> print(
    format_.strftime('EV%y%m%d_%H%M') + format_.strftime('%f')[:2]
)

EV190802_181802
```

Comment: Why not simply `dt.strftime('EV%y%m%d_%H%M%S')` => `'EV190802_181806'`?

Comment: Okay - but also note that the OP doesn't want `EV190802_181802` as the output. You can see this by running the code they wrote, which prints `EV20190802_181806`. (The question has a typo at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
import re

data = "2019-08-02 18:18:06.02887"
res = re.match(r'(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<day>\d{2})\s(?P<hours>\d{2}):(?P<minutes>\d{2}):(?P<seconds>\d{2}).(?P<miliseconds>\d+)',data)

out = f"EV{res.group('year')[2:]}{res.group('month')}{res.group('day')}_{res.group('hours')}{res.group('minutes')}{res.group('miliseconds')[:2]}"
print(out)
```

Output will be:

```
EV190802_181802
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `re.sub` here for a regex approach:

```
inp = "2019-08-02 18:18:06.02887"
output = re.sub(r'^\d{2}(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).*$',
                'EV\\1\\2\\3_\\4\\5\\6',
                inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
EV190802_181806
```

Note: Your expected output was actually given as `EV190802_181802`, but it appears to be a typo for my solution above, as I see no reason why you would *not* want to report seconds, but instead report hundreth fractions of a second.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all occurrences of `-`, `.` and `:`

   ```
    hello.replace("-","")
    hello.replace(".","")
    hello.replace(":","")
   ```
2. Get string in one line:

   ```
    print("EV" + hello[2:8] + "_" + hello[9:15])
   ```

Comment: Or just use `re.sub(r'[:.-]', '', hello)` for a one line way to strip off the punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex, just string splits and joins:

```
string = "2019-08-02 18:18:06.02887"
target = "EV190802_181806" 

d, t = string.split("20")[-1].split(".")[0].split(" ")
print("date:", d, "\ntime:", t)

d = "".join(d.split('-'))
t = "".join(t.split(':'))
result = "EV" + d + "_" + t
print("\nresult: ", result)

assert result == target

# >> out:
# date: 19-08-02 
# time: 18:18:06
# 
# result:  EV190802_181806
```

I make the assumption that you'd like to have "06" at the end of the target string (sorry if I'm mistaken!).