# python convert string to date time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string like this: `Monday April 27 2020, 5:14pm`
And I want to convert it to date time in python to become: `24-Apr-2020 5:14pm`
Would python be able to do that?

Comment: Yes, the `datetime.strptime` class method can parse a string to a datetime, and the `datetime.strftime` instance method can serialise it back to a string. Both require a *format string* which [lets you specify the format of each field](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
str_time = "Monday April 27 2020, 5:14pm"

formatted_time = datetime.strptime(a,"%A %B %d %Y, %I:%M%p")

new_str_representation = formatted_time.strftime("%d-%a-%Y %I:%M%p")
```

[Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

You can find more informations here.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27193139)

Comment: Thank you for your notice. I corrected myself

Comment: Found a library called dateutil that can do the work. Nice.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16115575/9008640