# How can I convert this date/time to yyyymmdd in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utc, python-datetime

I am given this `1974-11-27T00:00:00` but I don't know what you call this format so I can't find anything online on how to make this `yyyymmdd`

Comment: Have you done any research on how to parse and convert date formats in Python, for example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called an ISO formatted date time string. You can turn that into a datetime object by just doing:

```
import datetime
example = '1974-11-27T00:00:00'
d = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(example)
```

Now that's it's a date-time object, you can format it however you want:

```
print(d.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
>> 19741127
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a string, you can replace the `-` directly

```
s = '1974-11-27T00:00:00'
s = s[:10].replace('-','')
```

Answer (score 0):

To transform what you have into a date you can use python `datetime`:

```
import datetime
this_date = '1974-11-27T00:00:00'
# transform the string you have to a datetime type
your_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(this_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
# print it in the format you want to
print(your_date.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
19741127
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import datetime
str = '1974-11-27T00:00:00'
datetime.strptime(str,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

This date you have is in standard ISO 8601 format. To convert it into Python `datetime` object (assuming you have string) run

```
from datetime import datetime

s = '1974-11-27T00:00:00'
d = datetime.fromisoformat(s)
```

Once its a proper `datetime` instance you can format it anyway you want

```
print(d.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
19741127
```