# Converting input date from US format to European date format

Tags: python

Complete the following function that converts a US date to a European date. Days and months are padded (if necessary) to become two digits each.

Example: `europeanize('4/7/14')` returns `'07/04/12'`

Example: `europeanize('02/27/08')` returns `'27/02/08'`

This is what I have so far. I am trying to get the current date to return a European date.
Am I on the right track?

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
european_date = "2/12/2020"
def europeanize(date):
    if today == european_date:
        return european_date

print(today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Comment: You've got the right idea that you need to leverage `datetime` and `strftime()`. Assuming that you want the input and output of the function to be strings, think about converting the input string to a datetime object and then back into a string.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: This related question might contain the answers you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution.

```
from datetime import datetime 

def europeanize(date):
    european_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y').strftime("%d/%m/%y")
    return european_date
    
       
print(europeanize('11/9/14'))
```

`datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y')` converts the American date string to a datetime object which can then be manipulated as you wish into a string with `strftime`

Comment: @CourtneyMills Tested it and seems to run fine make sure you have datetime module installed.

Comment: The website I’m running it off of does not have the date time module installed. It only takes like import date time  etc...

Comment: @CourtneyMills Then you need to change `datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y')` to `datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y')`. This means that you will now go to the `datetime` module  and then get the rest.

Comment: "NotImplementedError: _strptime is not yet implemented in Skulpt on line 1" I get this error when I run the code

Comment: import datetime 

def europeanize(date):
    european_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y')
    return european_date
    
       
print(europeanize('11/9/14'))

Comment: @CourtneyMills You might want to change platforms at this point. Try it in repl.it.

Comment: What if dates are in list, how to convert them at once, I tried a lot, still unable to convert.