# Convert date/time string to a datetime.now() format

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to look at other stackoverflow posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format/16115575#16115575) about converting date & time strings to `datetime` objects but not having any luck for specifically what I am after.

```
from datetime import datetime

s = '2020-07-12T19:30'
f = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"
out = datetime.strptime(s, f)

print(out)
```

This works outputs `2020-07-12 19:30:00`

But how do I convert `s` for a format like `print(datetime.now())`?

Which prints like:
`datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 9, 12, 36, 24, 108816)`

Comment: What version of Python are you using? For `print(datetime.now())`, I get `2021-07-09 13:50:55.586161` on Python 3.8.0.

Comment: I am using anaconda Jupyter labs

Comment: But what version of *Python* are you using?

Comment: version 3.8 anaconda jupyter labs

Comment: It's just because you haven't captured seconds & microseconds I believe.
I was able to generate your desired outcome. (It wont show up if the value is zero)
Try giving this:
`s = '2020-07-12T19:30:1:2'`
`f = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f"`

Comment: That throws an error, `ValueError: time data '2020-07-12T19:30' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f'` Any ideas to try? Thanks so much...

Comment: I did not get the error because I've specified seconds & microseconds in the variable `s`. If you don't have seconds value in your data, then there's no way since, it shows up only non-zero values while printing. Try taking the varibles I took in my example

Comment: Oh got it I see I have add in seconds and microseconds to my data some how. The data comes from html form inputs to a date and time picker. That doesn't appear to automatically provide seconds and microseconds to my very limited knowledge