# Converting string in hours and minutes to datetime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime-format

I am given a list of time in military hours and minutes as a string. Naturally, I need to convert each string into a datetime object using the **strptime** class with the %H for military or 24-hour clock and %M for minutes. However, anytime I try to parse it I am getting an output for ***year,month,day hour.minute.seconds*** for no reason

ie.

```
from datetime import datetime
string_time = '18:00'
formatted_time = datetime.strptime(string_time, '%H:%M')

print(formatted_time)
```

> output:

> 1900-01-01 18:00:00

Just this morning when I was working on the assignment it printed perfectly fine but out of nowhere I started getting this weird output. Nowhere in my directory or current file did I ever try to format a year-month-day time. I did however try to create an empty datetime object but scrapped it after figuring out you can't have an empty datetime object.

Comment: What do you want to get instead?

Comment: the format I put. Hours:Minutes ie 18:00

Comment: So your desired output is equal to the input? Why do you use `strptime` then? Just use the input as it is?

Comment: `formatted_time.time().strftime('%H:%M')`

Comment: @mkrieger1 Because I need it as a datetime object. I am given 2 calenders along with duration and constraint where duration is length of meeting and constraint is when meetings can take place. I need to return a list of all possible meetings that I can schedule between the two calenders.

Comment: the calenders are a list of times that are already taken

Comment: i mean im almost certain i can solve it without having to use datetime but i think it would be ugly and much longer time complexity

Comment: Okay. In any case, your question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format

Comment: wait actually. this did not solve my question.. it reverts back to a strng.. I need it as a datetime... back to square one

Comment: `formatted_time` *is* a `datetime` (despite its name).

Comment: yes but the output is wrong i cant use it

Comment: Use strptime to convert a string to a datetime, do any calculations with it, and then use strftime to convert it to a string in the desired format.

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation

A `datetime` object, as its name implies, contains a *date* and a *time*. The reason your datetime object has a date `1900-01-01` even though you only specify the time is because the date of the datetime object cannot be empty (`1900-01-01` is the default date when no date is provided).

#### Solution

If you don't need to handle the "date", simply ignore the date part of your datetime object. If you need to print out the time, do `yourDateTimeObject.strftime('%H:%M')`.