# Change a specific string on each values of a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list like this :

```
list = [
    '20211231_2300',
    '20211231_2305',
    '20211231_2310',
    '20211231_2315',
    '20211231_2320',
    '20211231_2325'
]
```

With Python, I want to change each values of the list by `"2021/12/31_23:05"` to obtain this result:

```
[
    '2021/12/31_23:00',
    '2021/12/31_23:05',
    '2021/12/31_23:10',
    '2021/12/31_23:15',
    '2021/12/31_23:20',
    '2021/12/31_23:25'
]
```

How can I do that ?
Thank you !

Comment: Do you know how you can do it for a single string?

Comment: You may find [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format) helpful

Comment: You might not want to use type names as variable names.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Answer (score 1):

```
dates = [
    "20211231_2300",
    "20211231_2305",
    "20211231_2310",
    "20211231_2315",
    "20211231_2320",
    "20211231_2325",
]


def format_date(s: str) -> str:
    """assumes correct input format <yyyymmdd_hhmm>"""
    year = s[:4]
    month = s[4:6]
    day = s[6:8]
    hour = s[9:11]
    minute = s[11:]
    return f"{year}/{month}/{day}_{hour}:{minute}"


dates = [format_date(d) for d in dates]
print(dates)
```

Comment: Consider looking into the "datetime" lib - this string solution shouldn't be the solution of choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [`strptime` and `strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) from [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) standard library:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = [
    '20211231_2300',
    '20211231_2305',
    '20211231_2310',
    '20211231_2315',
    '20211231_2320',
    '20211231_2325'
]

fmt = [datetime.strptime(date, "%Y%m%d_%H%M").strftime("%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M") for date in dates] 

print(fmt) # prints: ['2021/12/31_23:00', '2021/12/31_23:05', '2021/12/31_23:10', '2021/12/31_23:15', '2021/12/31_23:20', '2021/12/31_23:25']
```