# Convert time to simple format

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I want to convert this time 2022-02-24T01:44:22 to 02/24/2022

```
since_date = 2022-02-24T01:44:22
print (since_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: `since_date = 2022-02-24T01:44:22` That is not valid python code.  Please post your real code.

Comment: `since_date` is already a string (according to the error), so you will need to [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) it into a datetime object before you can format it back into a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Comment: My code: since_date = (datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)- datetime.timedelta(20)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

I want to convert that output to desired output posted in the thread

Comment: It's hard to read code in comments.  Please update the question with the real code.

Comment: @Aaron88 Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your case:

```
from datetime import datetime 

date = datetime.strptime('2022-02-24T01:44:22', '%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S').strftime("%m/%d/%y")

print(date)
```

check [this link](https://strftime.org/) for other types of formatting.