# Convert Date time to human readable formate python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I have a date time string something like this

```
2022-03-21 16:29:01.8593
```

but I want it to be like

```
 03/21/2022 02:16 PM
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Comment: you'll want to use the python datetime library, https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html, to parse the first date using a specified format string, and then print it with a different format string.

Comment: @Esther No , I want diff output

Comment: @Esther didn't get can you please give a small example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.strptime('2022-03-21 16:29:01.8593', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
s = d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
```

Output:

```
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 21, 16, 29, 1, 859300)

>>> s
'03/21/2022 04:29 PM'
```

Use this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) as documentation.