# Concatenate and convert string to date in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, date, datetime

I have a string ‘2022.10.31’ and I want to convert it to ‘2022-10-31’ and then to date.

This is the R code:

```
pr1$dotvoranje <- paste(substr(pr1$dotvoranje, 1, 4), substr(pr1$dotvoranje, 6, 7), substr(pr1$dotvoranje, 9, 10), sep = "-")
pr1$dotvoranje <- as.Date(pr1$dotvoranje)
```

I need to do the following code in Python I found that I need to use .join() , but I have a column with strings that I need to convert to dates.

I started with this code (but I do not know how to use .join here). But this line only substracted the first four rows of that column. And I need to take that column and replace "."with "-".

```
depoziti['ddospevanje'] = depoziti['ddospevanje'].loc[0:4] + depoziti['ddospevanje'].loc[5:7] + depoziti['ddospevanje'].loc[8:10]
```

Comment: Can't you just `replace` the `.` with `-`?

Comment: I have tried, but how?

Comment: There's also: `datetime.datetime.strptime("2022.10.31", "%Y.%m.%d")`

Comment: You might consider using `strptime()` and `strftime()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Comment: Can you add a [mre] of your data? Are you using pandas?

Comment: Yes, I am using pandas and tried with dateutil. I have a table of over 250k rows with account, name and I have a string ''2022.12.31" that I want first to convert the "." to "-" and then into datetime (without showing UTC).

Answer (score 0):

Just putting it together

```
from datetime import datetime

dt1 = '2022.10.31'

dt2 = datetime.strptime(dt1, '%Y.%m.%d').date()

print ("type(dt2) :",  type(dt2))
print ("dt2       :", dt2)
```

Output

```
type(dt2) : <class 'datetime.datetime'>
dt2       : 2022-10-31
```

> Update : dt1 should be a series of string dates, not only one string... dt = ['2022.12.31', '2022.11.30'.....]

If it's a list, use list comprehension

```
dt1 = ['2022.10.31', '2022.10.1', '2022.9.1']
dt2 = [datetime.strptime(i, '%Y.%m.%d').date() for i in dt1]
dt2
```

If it's a column in pandas dataframe, this is one way of doing it

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'event' : ['x', 'y', 'z'],
      'date' : ['2022.10.31', '2022.10.1', '2022.9.1']})
df['date1'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x : datetime.strptime(x, '%Y.%m.%d').date())
df
```

Comment: dt1 should be a series of string dates, not only one string... dt = ['2022.12.31', '2022.11.30'.....]

Comment: @S_Star if you are receiving your strings in a list - you need to tell us this in your question, we can't read your mind.

Comment: Thank you @Geeths for the effort! I will try your solutions as well. 

Meanwhile, I have tried the following solution and it worked:
depoziti['ddospevanje'] = (depoziti['ddospevanje'].str.replace('.','-', regex = True).astype(str)) 

However, when I want to convert this column to datetime I got an error: 

value error: time data ""at position 274 doesn't match format specified

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that by "then to date" you mean you want a `datetime` object.

It is not necessary to do `string.replace()` in order to create the `datetime` object.

The `datetime` object uses syntax like `%Y` to refer to a year and so we will be using that with the function `strptime()` to ingest the date.

```
import datetime

date_as_string = "2022.10.31"
date_format = "%Y.%m.%d"

date = datetime.strptime(date_as_string, date_format)
```

Now you have a date time object.
If you want to then print out the date as a string, you can use `strftime()`

```
new_format = "%Y-%m-%d"

date_as_new_string = date.strftime(new_format)
print(date_as_new_string)
```

Further reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime 
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp -(This also contains a list of all the syntax for use with `strftime()` or `strptime()`)

---

if you are getting your dates (as strings) in a list, then just put the above code into a for loop:

```
import datetime


date_format = "%Y.%m.%d"
date_as_string_list =  ['2022.12.31', '2022.11.30']
date_list = []


for date_as_string in date_as_string_list:
    date_list.append(datetime.strptime(date_as_string, date_format))
```

now you have a list of datetime objects, and you can loop through them in order to get them as strings as already shown.

Comment: Hi @dafrandle, thank you for your effort as well. I am working with a series of dates which are objects, not with one string and strftime() or strptime() are for string, not series. I found how to replace dots to '-'. Now I need to convert that series in datetime, but I got value error.

Comment: @S_Star your question says you have strings, I'm not able to help further until you update your question to accurately say what you have.