# How to convert date in python

Tags: python, django

Iam using fullcalendar [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)

From my web template iam getting 2 dates in django a `startdate` and an `enddate`

Getting my startdate:

```
start = request.GET.get('start', None)
```

I need a `datetime` for my `django model`, so iam getting an `error`:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“Mon Feb 20 2023 16:07:47 GMT+0100 (Midden-Europese standaardtijd)” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

Can i convert it to datetime?

Comment: Probably you can configure the date format in javascript (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting) or convert between formats in python (https://stackoverflow.com/q/2265357/4046632)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("Mon Feb 20 2023 16:07:47 GMT+0100", "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z%z")
```

This will strip your string date into a datetime object

I recommend to also check this site for more info about datetime formatting: https://pynative.com/python-datetime-format-strftime/

Comment: Get the error "    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  (Midden-Europese standaardtijd)"

Comment: i could not figure out a way to get "Midden-Europese standaardtjjd)" just until GMT+0100

Comment: i replaced the "Midden-Europese standaardtjjd)" with ''. Then used datetime

Answer (score 0):

It can be easy to run into complications when working with dates, especially when dealing with different formats and time zones. One way to avoid these issues is to use the ISO format, which is widely adopted in various industries. Using a standard format ensures that your code is more easily understood and compatible with other systems. So, using ISO format to represent dates whenever possible is a good practice.

So, before doing a request to the server, you can convert your dates into an ISO format, for example:

```js
yourDate = 'Mon Feb 20 2023 16:07:47 GMT+0100 (Midden-Europese Standard Time)';
yourDateInIsoFormat = (new Date(yourDate)).toISOString();
```

The resulting string will be `2023-02-20T15:07:47.000Z`.

To parse an ISO format date in Python, you can use the `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()` function. However, there is a small glitch with this approach - only Python 3.11 have full support for all ISO formats. If you're using a version of Python prior to 3.11, you'll need to do a small fix.

**Python 3.7 to 3.10**:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_str = '2023-02-20T15:07:47.000Z'

# Replace the "Z" with "+00:00", since fromisoformat does not support UTC timezone offset
date_str = date_str.replace('Z', '+00:00')

# Parse the date string
date = datetime.fromisoformat(date_str)
```

**Python 3.11**:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_str = '2023-02-20T15:07:47.000Z'

# Parse the date string
date = datetime.fromisoformat(date_str)
```

Also, there is another alternative, use `python-dateutil` package:

```py
from dateutil import parser

date_str = "2023-02-20T15:07:47.000Z"

# Parse the date string
date = parser.parse(date_str)
```

The three options will return a correct date.