# How can i convert from 03MAR23 format to yyyy-mm-dd in python

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I wanted to convert from 03FEB23 format to yyyy-mm-dd in python
how can I do it?

Use the below code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df=spark.createDataFrame([["1"]],["id"])
df.select(current_date().alias("current_date"), \
      date_format("03MAR23","yyyy-MMM-dd").alias("yyyy-MMM-dd")).show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Comment: ```datetime.strptime('03FEB23', "%d%b%y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")```

Comment: careful with the tags next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***In pyspark:***

Try with `to_date` function with `ddMMMyy` format.

**`Examples:`**

```
select to_date('03MAR23','ddMMMyy')
--2023-03-03
```

---

***Dataframe API:***

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([["03MAR23"]],["dt"])
df.withColumn("dt1", to_date(col("dt"),"ddMMMyy")).show()
#+-------+----------+
#|     dt|       dt1|
#+-------+----------+
#|03MAR23|2023-03-03|
#+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

date_str = '03FEB23'
date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d%b%y')
formatted_date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(formatted_date) # Output: 2023-02-03
```