# Is there a way to specify which value you want to use with python's .split function?

Tags: python

I am trying to take a date and transform it to make it compatible with the MySQL "Date" format.

So I currently have a CSV file with the date in the following format DD-MM-YYYY. however the MySQL "date" format only accepts YYYY-MM-DD.

I have been able to get my program to read the date from the CSV file and store it as a local variable. From here I was thinking to use the .split function with the delimiter being "-". I would then be able to store each section of the date (For example YYYY would be stored as "Year") and then reassemble the date, just in the correct format.

However I am unable to find anything online on if it is possible to do this using the .split function. I want to ,for example, take the first string from .split and turn that into its own string but I cannot find a way to specify that I only want the section of the variable before the first delimiter.

any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: `split()` returns a list.  So for example `date_parts = "DD-MM-YYYY".split("-")` will return the list `["DD", "MM", "YYYY"]`.  Then you can access whatever part of that list you want to, i.e. `date_parts[0]` for the day or `date_parts[2]` for the year.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: You can just reverse the list that is returned by `split()` and use `join` to stitch it back together. If your date is stored in `dt` then: `'-'.join(dt.split('-')[::-1])`

Comment: `x = mydate.split('-')`, `newdate = '-'.join((x[2],x[1],x[0]))`.

Comment: Are you looking for `datetime.datetime.strptime("20-10-2020", "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`? Maybe check out [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could also use the dateutil library.
For example with something like this:

```
from dateutil import parser

date_string = '31-12-2021'

# Parse the input date string using dateutil
date_obj = parser.parse(date_string, dayfirst=True)

# re-Format the date object in YYYY-MM-DD format
new_date_string = date_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(new_date_string)
```

Result:

```
2021-12-31
```

Install it with:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Docs here:

```
https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
```

Comment: Why use `dateutil` when the format is known and `datetime.datetime.strptime` exists in the standard library?

Comment: I wanted to give a hint to have a look at specialized libs when dealing with dates, date formats etc. This makes life often easier when transforming date formats. This often cannot be done correctly by "just" manipulating strings. For simple string manipulation you are absolutely right.

Comment: The builtin `datetime` isn't a string manipulation module. It already contains the functionality you suggested OP install dateutil for

Comment: I used dateutil in projects and found it very convenient. Sometimes datetime seams a bit too raw for me. So for me if nothing speaks against adding a lib I would prefer dateutil over datetime in general. But that has to be decided by everyone individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard Python library `datetime` to do what you intend:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_str = "01-12-2023"  # Assume format DD-MM-YYYY

# parse the original date using strptime
original_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d-%m-%Y')

# use datetime to convert the date to the pretended format
mysql_date = original_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(mysql_date)  # Output: '2023-12-01'
```

You could also do it by using the split method (former solution is recommended over this one):

```py
original_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d-%m-%Y')

# since we can assume the date is in format DD-MM-YY
# split('-') will return list [DD, MM, YY]
day, month, year = original_date.split('-')

# in the end just put it together in the order you need
mysql_date = f'{year}-{month}-{day}'
```