# Converting a string to datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse date and format it using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-and-format-it-using-python)

i have a date string like `2011-07-15 13:00:00+00:00` . Any way to convert this string to a datetime object in python ?

Thank You

Comment: Step 1.  Search.  Step 2.  Read.  Step 3.  Close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse date and format it using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-and-format-it-using-python) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713594/parsing-dates-and-times-from-strings-using-python and numerous others.

Comment: Really would be better to at least mark this as a duplicate of a date_time_-related question, not date. Both of the questions linked are for dates, which may have some different answers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 11):

You can handle the time zone appropriately, and have the format recognized automatically, if you use `dateutil.parser`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime/470303#470303):

```
from dateutil import parser
dt = parser.parse("2011-07-15 13:00:00+00:00")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the strptime function in the datetime module. http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-07-15 13:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

**Edit:**

Lesson learnt, the datetime module isn't capable of doing this, at least on my platform. Mu Mind's solution seems to be the easiest way to do this robustly according to http://wiki.python.org/moin/WorkingWithTime

Comment: Could you please give an example, like considering the string above. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply when i do datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-07-15 13:00:00+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') im getting 'ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00:00' :( . Is there some error in my format string ?

Comment: The dateutil.parser worked for me. I have not been successful with the strptime. It just doesn't seem to work on Windows XP?