# String date to date object in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing Dates and Times from Strings using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713594/parsing-dates-and-times-from-strings-using-python)

I'm reading a string

```
"2011-06-11"
```

How can I cast this to a **date** object?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-and-format-it-using-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713594/parsing-dates-and-times-from-strings-using-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know it will be in that format, you can use the [`strptime` function](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

(and it's *not* a cast, you're actually creating a new date out of the string)

If you don't know the format of the date, I suggest looking at [the dateutil](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) module which provides a powerful date parsing function.

Comment: I know, but it's a static method which doesn't take a class parameter, so it's called the same way as a non-member function. I thought it easier to just call it a function. (Plus technically there _is_ an actual Python function at work behind the scenes.)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [105]: import datetime as dt
```

This parses the string and returns a `dt.datetime` object:

```
In [106]: dt.datetime.strptime('2011-06-11',"%Y-%m-%d")
Out[106]: datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 11, 0, 0)
```

This returns a `dt.date` object:

```
In [108]: dt.datetime.strptime('2011-06-11',"%Y-%m-%d").date()
Out[108]: datetime.date(2011, 6, 11)
```

The `strptime` method is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), and the format string `"%Y-%m-%d"` is explained [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-06-11', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2011-06-11", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Also check out [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-iso-formatted-date-in-python)