# Xpath extract dates between certain characters AND use as dates

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

**UPDATE**: Regarding my 2nd question (how to convert string to date format in MySQL), I found a way and want to share it:

1) Save the "string date" data as VARCHAR (Don't use TEXT)

2) When showing MySQL data in PHP or other ways, use the function of **str_to_date**(string-date-column, *date-format*), such as the following example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM yourtablename ORDER BY str_to_date(string-date-column, '%d %M %Y')";
```

---

I am using scrapy to collect data, write to database.  From a website, the post date of each item is listed as following:

```
<p>   #This is the last <p> within each <div>
<br>
[15 May 2015, #9789]
<br>
</p>
```

So the date is always behind a "**[**" and before a "**,**".  I used the following xpath code to extract:

```
sel.xpath("p[last()]/text()[contains(., '[')]").extract()
```

But I will get the whole line:

```
[15 May 2015, #9789]
```

So, how to get only the part of "**15 May 2015**"? If this can be done, how to convert the scraped string (15 May 2015) as real DATE data, so it can be used for sorting?  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more "scrapic" approach would involve using the [built-in regular expression support](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions) in the XPath expressions and/or `.re()`.

This is with both applied:

```
In [1]: response.xpath("p[last()]/text()[re:test(., '\[\d+ \w+ \d{4}\, #\d+\]')]").re(r"\d+ \w+ \d{4}")
Out[1]: [u'15 May 2015']
```

Or, this is when you use `.re()` to extract the date locating the element as you did before:

```
In [2]: response.xpath("p[last()]/text()[contains(., '[')]").re(r"\d+ \w+ \d{4}")
Out[2]: [u'15 May 2015']
```

Comment: Your "scrapic" approach works perfectly, alecxe!  Do you have suggestions regarding use the "[u'15 May 2015']" output as date instead of string while considering scrapy and mysql usage in the whole picture?  Will MySQL automatically recognized "[u'15 May 2015']" as date if I define that column as "date" type?

Comment: @LearnAWK I would recommend being more explicit and operate with actual dates - it would also catch the errors earlier providing an additional validation.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first question, assuming that there is maximum one date at a time, you can use combination of XPath `substring-after()` and `substring-before()` functions to get `15 May 2015` part of the text node :

```
substring-before(substring-after(p[last()]/text()[contains(., '[')], '['), ',')
```

Regarding the second question, you can use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert string to `datetime` :

```
import datetime

result = datetime.datetime.strptime("15 May 2015", "%d %b %Y")
print(result)
print(type(result))
```

**output :**

```
2015-05-15 00:00:00
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: The second part of the question is [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1713594/190597).

Comment: While trying to use the datetime function, I got the following error message: "exceptions.ValueError: time data "[u'15 May 2015']" does not match format '%d-%b-%Y'".  Is it because Scrapy add special characters before and after the scraped string of "15 May 2015"?

Comment: Related question: If I will put my data into MySQL anyway, will strings like "15 May 2015" be recognized as dates as long as I define that column as date type of data in MySQL?

Comment: That's because the correct format, as demonstrated above, is "%d %b %Y" with no dash involved

Comment: Well, after I change it to "%d %b %Y", I still get the same error message: " exceptions.ValueError: time data "[u'20 May 2015']" does not match format '%d %b %Y' "