# Best way to get date strings with Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, date

What's the best way to get datestrings from a website using Python?

The datestrings can be, for example, in the forms of:

- April 1st, 2011
- April 2nd, 2011
- April 23, 2011
- 4/2/2011
- 04/23/2011

Would this have to be a ton of regex?  What's the most elegant solution?

Comment: Yes, this is a pattern matching problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any python library for parsing dates and times from a natural language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495487/is-there-any-python-library-for-parsing-dates-and-times-from-a-natural-language)

Comment: Are you only looking for English month names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this lib: http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/

From its examples Wiki page, here are a couple of formats it can handle that look relevant to your question:

```
result = p.parseDateText("March 5th, 1980") 
result = p.parseDate("4/4/80")
```

EDIT: now I notice it's actually a duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495487/is-there-any-python-library-for-parsing-dates-and-times-from-a-natural-language) where the same library was recommended!

Comment: I ended up using six regex strings to find the most common date formats, but I'll give you the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
    month = '(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|nov|dec)[a-z]{0,6}'
    regex_strings = ['%s(\.| )\d{1,2},? \d{2,4}' % month, # Month.Day, Year
                     '\d{1,2} %s,? \d{4}' % month, # Day Month Year(4)
                     '%s \d{1,2}\w{2},? \d{4}' % month, # Mon Day(th), Year
                     '\d{1,2} %s' % month, # Day Month
                     '\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}', # Month.Day.Year
                     '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}', # Month/Day/Year{2,4}
                     ]
```