# Converting different dates formats into date time

Tags: python, datetime

How do I check a body text for different date formats and convert it into datetime format?
The body of text could be:

May 6 2014 (can use parser here)

Tue May 6 2014 

mm/dd/yyyy , yyyy/mm/dd etc

yyyy:dd::mm, mm:dd:yyyy

and so on. 

Is there an easy way to check what format the date is in ?

Comment: related: [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/466345/4279)

Comment: related: [Python date string to date object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2803852/4279)

Answer (score 1):

[`python-dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) module is pretty good at parsing datetime strings in different formats:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('May 6 2014')
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 6, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse('Tue May 6 2014')
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 6, 0, 0)
```

Also see:

- [datetime from string in Python, best-guessing string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507648/datetime-from-string-in-python-best-guessing-string-format)
- [Extracting date from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python)