# Can we Auto detect Datetime format of given column from csv file?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, datetime, timestamp

Suppose I have a `csv` with a `timestamp` but the format is not defined. It can be of any format with any separator like -

`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm` or `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` or `mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm` or `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` or just like that.

I am trying to parse dates of any format.

Here:

```
dateparse = lambda dates: datetime.strptime(dates, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

We have defined to parse dates in this format: `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M`

If anyone can give any valuable suggestion then it will be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datetime from string in Python, best-guessing string format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507648/datetime-from-string-in-python-best-guessing-string-format)

Comment: Are the date formats within an individual csv file in a consistent format? If not then it is not possible to distinguish between, for example, 1st February and 2nd January.

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) has an `infer_datetime_format` parameter:

> infer_datetime_format : boolean, default False
>
> If True and parse_dates is enabled, pandas will attempt to infer the format of the datetime strings in the columns, and if it can be inferred, switch to a faster method of parsing them. In some cases this can increase the parsing speed by ~5-10x.

Answer (score 0):

[DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/) is a SQL OLAP DBMS which includes a very powerful CSV parser that can automatically detect file format, headers, column types and more
https://duckdb.org/2023/10/27/csv-sniffer.html

It also includes a [PythonAPI](https://docs.conda.io/) to use DuckDB directly or through [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/).

you just load the library and include your CSV in a memory table

```
import duckdb
duckdb.sql("CREATE TABLE temptable AS SELECT * from read_csv_auto('myfile.csv'")
```

So that you can later do whatever queries to your table

```
duckdb.sql("SUMMARIZE SELECT * from temptable")
```