# Formatting various date/time format to a common format in Python

Tags: python, date, format

I am looking for a way to format different date and time strings to a common format. For example, i get date/time data in various following formats:

- "Mon, Aug 7th 2023"
- "Fri, 04 Aug 2023 18:16:02 +0530"
- "7-Aug-23"
- "August 7, 2023"
- "August 9, 2023 19:12 IST"
- "2023-08-07T21:31:45.000Z"
- "2023-08-07T20:45:09"
- "8/5/2023 21:22"

I am looking for a way to convert these different format to common format such as DD/MM/YYYY in python.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [datetime from string in Python, best-guessing string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507648/datetime-from-string-in-python-best-guessing-string-format)

Comment: Thanks @matszwecja. That did help, however it didnt work for date such as "Fri, August 4, 2023, 20:54 pm".