# Python: convert complicated date and time string to timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I want to know how to convert this date format

```
"Thu 21st Aug '14, 4:58am"
```

to a timestamp with Python?

Another format that I need to convert:

```
"Yesterday, 7:22am"
```

I tried parse util without success...

Answer (score 7):

If you haven't done so already, have a look at the `parse` function in [`dateutils.parser`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) for parsing strings representing dates...

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> dt = parse("Thu 21st Aug '14, 4:58am")
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 21, 4, 58)
```

...and then to convert a `datetime` object to a timestamp, you can do the following:

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
1408593480.0
```

As side remark, `parse` is a useful function which can recognise a huge range of different date formats. However it's sometimes *too* helpful and sees dates where perhaps a date is not intended:

```
>>> parse("14, m 23")
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 23, 0, 14)
```

If you also want to parse expressions such as "Yesterday, 7:22am", you could do one of two things:

1. Replace "yesterday", "yester-day", "yday" and other variations with "25/08/2014" (or another appropriate date) and then use `parse` on the new string.
2. Use another library to parse the string. [parsedatetime](https://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/) is one option...

Here's parsedatetime in action on your example:

```
>>> import parsedatetime.parsedatetime as pdt
>>> p = pdt.Calendar()
>>> d = p.parse("Yesterday, 7:22am")
>>> d
((2014, 8, 25, 7, 22, 0, 0, 237, -1), 3)
```

To turn this date representation `d` into a `datetime` object, you can unpack the tuple like so:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(*d[0][:7])
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 25, 7, 22)
```

Now `dt` can be easily converted to a timestamp in the way described above.

Comment: and to create a timestamp?

Comment: parse util cant parse this format: "Yesterday, 7:22am" what can i do to parse this format to timestamp?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495487/is-there-any-python-library-for-parsing-dates-and-times-from-a-natural-language) recommends [parsedatetime](https://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/). Looks promising.

Comment: @user3458842 - I've updated my answer to include your new example.

Comment: you could use `p.parseDT()` instead of `p.parse()`, to get `datetime()` object.

Comment: `mktime()` may return a wrong result sometimes (50% chance during a end-of-DST transition). You could use `tz = tzlocal.get_localzone(); aware_dt = tz.localize(dt, is_dst=None)`, to assert that the input time is unambiguous. And `timestamp = (aware_dt - epoch).total_seconds()`, to get POSIX timestamp,  where `epoch = datetime(1970,1,1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 a = "Thu 21st Aug '14, 4:58am"
 datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%a %dst %b \'%y, %H:%M%p')
```