# Python DataFrame: How to convert time (formatted as a string) into seconds?

Tags: python, pandas, function, datetime, time

I have a DataFrame that has time that has a 'Time Taken' column. The format is not a usual timestamp so I am struggling. The below is an extract of the column.

```
1 min 50 secs
2 mins 10 secs
40 secs
```

How can I convert this column to produce an output in seconds? The below is what I am looking for.

```
110
130
40
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: what is the exact format? Is it strings as shown? Can you show sample of the dataframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse free-text time intervals in Python, ranging from years to seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775743/how-can-i-parse-free-text-time-intervals-in-python-ranging-from-years-to-second)

Comment: see also [How to construct a timedelta object from a simple string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4628122/10197418)

Comment: @JustinOberle yes, the format is just strings as shown

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `datetime` library to parse the strings. I would recommend standardizing the dataframe strings so that you can use a single parser for the times.

```
from datetime import datetime

time = "1 min 50 secs"

dt = datetime.strptime(time,'%M min %S secs')

secs = dt.minute*60 + dt.second
print(secs)

110
```

Comment: @MrFuppes That is why I mentioned standardizing the strings. If the OP changes the 40 secs to 0 min 40 secs it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pd.to_timedelta function of pandas.

**Input**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ["1 min 50 secs", "2 mins 10 secs", "40 secs"]})


    time
0   1 min 50 secs
1   2 mins 10 secs
2   40 secs
```

**Solution using pd.to_timedelta**

```
df['timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.time.str.replace('secs','sec')
                .str.replace('mins', 'min')).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
    time           timedelta
0   1 min 50 secs   110
1   2 mins 10 secs  130
2   40 secs         40
```