# What is the difference between `a, b = b, a+b` and `a = b; b = a+b` for fibonacci

Tags: python, python-2.7, fibonacci

I'm new to python so I want to ask you a question..

Previously while I was writing a fibonacci function I tryed to replace

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

with

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

Believing that it was the same thing but I noted that the output is different (and wrong)
Shouldn't these two codes do the same thing?
Here it is the full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def main(args):
    fibonacci(1000)
    return 0

def fibonacci(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
         print b,
         a, b = b, a+b # if I comment this and decomment the two line below it shows me a different output 
        # a = b
        # b = a + b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: on the first one, the calculation for the new value of `b` is carried out with the old value of `a`. On the second one with the new one.

Comment: This is explained in the Python tutorial itself, [First Steps Towards Programming](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming)

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405818/why-doesn-t-executing-a-x-x-a-twice-result-in-a-change-of-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you do:

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

`a` will hold the previous value of b and `b` will hold `a+b` based on previous value.

But when you do:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

Value of `a` is updated to `b` during `a=b` and hence `a+b` will have different result as `a` is now updated.

For example, see simple code to swap two values. It is possible because of the on the fly change in values:

```
>>> a , b = 5, 10
>>> a, b = b, a
>>> a, b
(10, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

`b, a+b` is the same as `(b, a+b)` (a tuple). When you do `a, b = b, a+b` you implicilty assign the first element to the variable on the left and the second value to the variable on the right.

In your replacement, you changed `a`'s value *before* calculating `b`, which didn't happen before.

So, if we assume `a = 1` and `b = 2`, we have:

```
a, b = (2, 1+2)
>> print(a)
>> 2
>> print(b)
>> 3
```

In your latter example, we'd have:

```
a = 2
b = 2 + 2
>> print(a)
>> 2
>> print(b)
>> 4
```