# What does a, b=b, a%b mean in a definition?

Tags: python

Found it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95521/gcd-using-euclid-algorithm)

Also, does it read right to left or vice versa?

Comment: Please include any code relevant to your question in the question itself, not via links. But to answer the question, it's just a shorthand way to assign to both the `a` and `b` variables at once. It's like `a = b` then `b = a%b` but where the second assignment is using the *original* value of `a` rather than the new one. For example `a, b = b, a` lets you swap two variables over without requiring a temporary variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python's comma operator works during assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502268/how-does-pythons-comma-operator-works-during-assignment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standardized method to swap two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple assignment and evaluation order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-and-evaluation-order-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

In assignment statements in python, the right-hand side is evaluated first before doing the actual setting of variables. So,

```
a , b = b, a%b
```

evaluates b (let's call the result `temp1`), evaluates a%b which is a mod b (call that `temp2`), then sets `a` to `temp1` and `b` to `temp2`.