# Add one month to a given date (rounded day after) with Python

Tags: python, pandas, calendar, timedelta, python-dateutil

I'd like to add one month to a given date

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(year=2014, month=5, day=2)
```

so I should get

```
datetime.datetime(year=2014, month=6, day=2)
```

but with

```
dt = datetime.datetime(year=2015, month=1, day=31)
```

I should get

```
datetime.datetime(year=2015, month=3, day=1)
```

because there is no 2015-02-31 (and I want my result being round one day **after**)

Some months have 31 days, some other 30, some 29, some 28 !

so adding a `datetime.timedelta` is probably not a good manner of doing (because we don't know the number of days to add)

I noticed that Pandas have an interesting concept of `DateOffset`

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects

but I didn't find a `Month` offset, just `MonthBegin` or `MonthEnd`

I see also this post
[How do I calculate the date six months from the current date using the datetime Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546321/how-do-i-calculate-the-date-six-months-from-the-current-date-using-the-datetime)

so I tried `dateutil.relativedelta` but

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
datetime.datetime(year=2015, month=1, day=31)+relativedelta(months=1)
```

returns

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28, 0, 0)
```

so result was rounded one day **before**.

Is there a (clean) way to round day **after** ?

edit:
I gave an example with one month to add but I also want to be able to add for example : 2 years and 6 months (using a `relativedelta(years=2, months=6)`)

Comment: Would you ever want to add, for example, 2 years, 6 months, and 5 days? Can you please be more specific in your question?

Comment: I just need to add years and months to a datetime (but I want result to be "round" day after, not day before like relativedelta is doing)

Comment: I've edited my answer below so that it accepts a `relativedelta` argument. This will allow you to use whatever time you want. Note that it won't work if you include days, hours, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) and manually check the [`datetime.day`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.day) attribute, if the original day is greater than the new day, then add a day.

The function below accepts a `datetime` object and `relativedelta` object. Note that the code below only works for years and months, I don't believe it'll work if you use anything below that (days, hours, etc). You could easily modify this function to take `years` and `months` as arguments and then construct the `relativedelta` inside the function itself.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def add_time(d, rd):
    day = relativedelta(days=+1)

    out = d + rd
    if d.day > out.day:
        out = out + day

    return out    

# Check that it "rolls over"
print(add_time(datetime(year=2015, month=1, day=29), relativedelta(years=+4, months=+1))) # 2019-03-01 00:00:00
print(add_time(datetime(year=2015, month=3, day=31), relativedelta(years=+0, months=+2))) # 2015-05-01 00:00:00

# Check that it handles "normal" scenarios
print(add_time(datetime(year=2015, month=6, day=19), relativedelta(months=+1))) # 2015-07-19 00:00:00
print(add_time(datetime(year=2015, month=6, day=30), relativedelta(years=+2, months=+1))) # 2017-07-30 00:00:00

# Check across years
print(add_time(datetime(year=2015, month=12, day=25), relativedelta(months=+1))) # 2016-01-25 00:00:00

# Check leap years
print(add_time(datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=29), relativedelta(years=+4, months=+1))) # 2020-02-29 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work. It is quite clean, but not beautiful:

```
def add_month(now):
    try:
        then = (now + relativedelta(months=1)).replace(day=now.day)
    except ValueError:
        then = (now + relativedelta(months=2)).replace(day=1)
    return then

for now in [datetime(2015, 1, 20), datetime(2015, 1, 31), datetime(2015, 2, 28)]:
    print now, add_month(now)
```

prints:

```
2015-01-20 00:00:00 2015-02-20 00:00:00
2015-01-31 00:00:00 2015-03-01 00:00:00
2015-02-28 00:00:00 2015-03-28 00:00:00
```

It adds one month and tries to replace the day with the original day. If it succeeds, it is no special case. If it fails (ValueError), we have to add another month and go to its first day.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

```
import datetime
import calendar
dt = datetime.datetime(year=2014, month=5, day=2)
d = calendar.monthrange(dt.year,dt.month+1)[1] 
print dt+datetime.timedelta(days=d+1)
```

Output for the first input `(year=2014, month=5, day=2)`:

```
2014-06-02 00:00:00
```

Output for the second input `(year=2015, month=1, day=31)`:

```
2015-03-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the bellow method:

```
def datetime_offset_by_months(datetime_origin, n=1):
    """
    datetime offset by months
    :param datetime_origin: the original datetime
    :param n: count of months
    :return: after offset datetime
    """
    # create a shortcut object for one day
    one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    # first use div and mod to determine year cycle
    q, r = divmod(datetime_origin.month + n, 12)

    # create a datetime_offset
    # to be the last day of the target month
    datetime_offset = datetime.datetime(
        datetime_origin.year + q, r + 1, 1) - one_day

    '''
       if input date is the last day of this month
       then the output date should also be the last
       day of the target month, although the day
       www.iplaypy.com
       may be different.
       for example:
       datetime_origin = 8.31
       datetime_offset = 9.30
    '''

    if datetime_origin.month != (datetime_origin + one_day).month:
        return datetime_offset

    '''
        if datetime_origin day is bigger than last day of
        target month, then, use datetime_offset
        for example:
        datetime_origin = 10.31
        datetime_offset = 11.30
    '''

    if datetime_origin.day >= datetime_offset.day:
        return datetime_offset

    '''
     then, here, we just replace datetime_offset's day
     with the same of datetime_origin, that's ok.
    '''

    return datetime_offset.replace(day= datetime_origin.day)
```

the usage of it:

```
import datetime
now_date = datetime.datetime.now()

off_set_datetime = datetime_offset_by_months(now_date, -2)
print(off_set_datetime)
```