# Pandas - Python, deleting rows based on Date column

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

I'm trying to delete rows of a dataframe based on one date column; `[Delivery Date]`

I need to delete rows which are older than 6 months old but not equal to the year '1970'.

I've created 2 variables:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
sixmonthago = date.today() - timedelta(188)

import time
nineteen_seventy = time.strptime('01-01-70', '%d-%m-%y')
```

but I don't know how to delete rows based on these two variables, using the `[Delivery Date]` column.

Could anyone provide the correct solution?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can just filter them out:

```
df[(df['Delivery Date'].dt.year == 1970) | (df['Delivery Date'] >= sixmonthago)]
```

This returns all rows where the year is 1970 or the date is less than 6 months.

You can use boolean indexing and pass multiple conditions to filter the df, for multiple conditions you need to use the array operators so `|` instead of `or`, and parentheses around the conditions due to operator precedence.

Check the docs for an explanation of [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: Thanks.. I'm getting a return error: TypeError: 'Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values' - probably needs its own seperate question but does this mean I have to change the [Delivery Date] to datetime? Sorry, I'm quite new to this

Comment: You mave have strings instead of datetimes, you can convert doing `df['Delivery Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Delivery Date'])`

Answer (score 4):

Be sure the calculation itself is accurate for "6 months" prior. You may not want to be hardcoding in 188 days. Not all months are made equally.

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546321/how-do-i-calculate-the-date-six-months-from-the-current-date-using-the-datetime
six_months = date.today() - relativedelta( months = +6 )
```

Then you can apply the following logic.

```
import time
nineteen_seventy = time.strptime('01-01-70', '%d-%m-%y')

df = df[(df['Delivery Date'].dt.year == nineteen_seventy.tm_year) | (df['Delivery Date'] >= six_months)]
```

If you truly want to drop sections of the dataframe, you can do the following:

```
df = df[(df['Delivery Date'].dt.year != nineteen_seventy.tm_year) | (df['Delivery Date'] < six_months)].drop(df.columns)
```

Comment: hey this is returning the error: drop() takes at least 2 arguments, 1 given