# python 3 Delete row from csv based on Date Column (string format)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, datetime

I was trying to fit my scenario with the below - but failed

[Pandas - Python, deleting rows based on Date column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629154/pandas-python-deleting-rows-based-on-date-column)

I have a output.csv file with the following columns

```
Customer, Alertkey, Node, Alertgroup, FirstOccurrence,
TKT_Flag, X733SpecificProb, TKT_TicketNumber, TKT_Keyword
```

The file will be updated from database every 7 days incrementally with last 7 days data

So ideally I have to drop the first 7 days of data from the file itself.

I could write below but getting type error "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil import parser


df=pd.read_csv('output.csv', usecols=['FirstOccurrence'],parse_dates=[0])
df=df['FirstOccurrence'].iloc[0]
dt = parser.parse(df)
SevenDays = dt + relativedelta( days = +7 )
df=df[(parser.parse(df['FirstOccurrence']) < SevenDays)].drop(df.columns)
```

There will be millions of lines. I am copying first few lines from 1st Jan 2016. But it will be from 1st Jan 2016 to till date. Every week it will append and should delete records of first 7 days - i.e first time it should delete records from 1st Jan to 6th Jan and so on

```
Customer,Alertkey,Node,Alertgroup,FirstOccurrence,TKT_Flag,X733SpecificProb,TKT_TicketNumber,TKT_Keyword
Cust1,Cust1_11_53_Services_Warning,Node_Cust1,ITM_K53_SERVICEMON,2016-01-01 00:12:59,1005,TOLPUKC_OS:25223174,INC000014799786,CGMIDDLEWARE_MEDIUM_CONNECTDIRECT
Cust1,Cust1_11_53_Services_Warning,Node1_Cust1,ITM_K53_SERVICEMON,2016-01-01 00:12:59,1005,TOLPUKC_OS:25223175,INC000014799785,CGMIDDLEWARE_MEDIUM_CONNECTDIRECT
Cust2,Cust2_21_NT_System_CPU_Critical,Cust2_Node8,ITM_NT_System,2016-01-01 00:15:48,101,PARPFRC_OS:21192843,INC000000628410,WINDOWS_MEDIUM_DEFPRODUCTSILVER
Cust3,Cust3_10352_LZ_TDW_DISK_Critica,Cust3_Node22,ITM_Linux_Disk,2016-01-01 00:17:05,200,TOLPUKC_OS:25223370,INC000001412280,CGMOM_HIGH_DEFPRODUCT
Cust6,Cust6_11_53_Services_Warning,Cust6_Node700,ITM_K53_SERVICEMON,2016-01-01 00:22:36,22,TOLPUKC_OS:25223601,INC000002250120,CGIOWINTELIMOC_MEDIUM_DEFPRODUCT
```

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message.

Comment: Your code says drop columns not rows?

Comment: Error as below
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Anirban_Backup/Drive_D/W0rk/Script/Python/DataBase_Connection/Delete_Rows_BasedOnTime.py", line 10, in <module>
    df=df[(parser.parse(df['FirstOccurrence']) < SevenDays)].drop(df.columns)

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: DYZ
Error as below
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
File "D:/Anirban_Backup/Drive_D/W0rk/Script/Python/DataBase_Connection/Delete_Rows_BasedOnTime.py", line 10, in <module>
    df=df[(parser.parse(df['FirstOccurrence']) < SevenDays)].drop(df.columns)
TypeError: string indices must be integers. 
dartdog No idea hw

Answer (score 0):

replace this : 
`df=df[(parser.parse(df['FirstOccurrence']) < SevenDays)].drop(df.columns)`

with: 
`df = df.drop(df[(parser.parse(df['FirstOccurrence']) < SevenDays)].index, inplace=True)`

try this hope this help you.

Comment: <module>
    df = df.drop(df[(parser.parse(df['FirstOccurrence']) < SevenDays)].index, inplace=True)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'drop'