# How to adding month to date in and return in Date format in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, date, robotframework

I try to calculate month.

My Example code: 27/01/2020 + 20 months

```
Test Date
   ${PAYMENTDATE}    Set Variable    27/01/2020
   ${PAYMENTDATE}    Convert Date    ${PAYMENTDATE}    date_format=%d/%m/%Y    result_format=%Y-%m-%d
   ${DATE}   Add Time To Date    ${PAYMENTDATE}   20 months      result_format=%d/%m/%Y
   log to console     ${DATE}
```

But it not work, Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are providing time value in months which is not valid. Unfortunately adding months to the date is not possible using the Robotframework DateTime library. From the DateTime documentation:

> time: Time that is added in one of the supported [time formats](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Time%20formats).

You need to provide the time value in one of the possible way e.g. You can provide days.

20 months approximates to 600 days and below code works without problem.

```
${DATE}   Add Time To Date    ${PAYMENTDATE}   600 days      result_format=%d/%m/%Y
```

In case you are looking for exact days to be added for 20 months than you need to calculate exact number of days starting from the date you want to add 20 months to and provide it in above code instead of 600 days. You can easily find answers on how to calculate exact days using python like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4406260/415749).