# Deducting x number of months from a given date

Tags: python, datetime

Is there a way to deduct a specified number of months from a given date.  So for example, if the day is 2006/02/27. Then I want to backtrack 3 months and find the months within this date and 3 months back. In this case, it would be Feb, Jan & dec. What I am really after is finding a range of months.

I can think of using timedelta and specifying 93 days (31 x 3). But this could potentially be a problem if its early month date. something like 01/03/2006 - 93 days will perhaps result in a date in november/2005, which will include march, Feb,Jan,Dec,Nov as months. But what I want is March,Feb and Jan

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
someDate = datetime(2006,2,27) 
newDate =someDate - timedelta(days = 3)
#someDate - 3months
```

Any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: This problem has no general solution - for example, what is 2020/05/31 minus 3 months? February has no 31th, even on a leap year.

Comment: Is [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52478319/10041823) answers ?

Comment: Thanks Alexandre B. Thats exactly what I am looking for