# how to calculate date after 8 months from delivery_date?

Tags: python, django, web

I want to make a function that returns the expiration date.
this is the field to calculate from?

```
delivery_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Do you want this field as an annotation in a query or as a property/function onn the model?

Comment: function on the model.

Answer (score 1):

this is how to do it in python:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date_of_interest = date.today() # get this from your app
eight_months = date_of_interest + relativedelta(months=+8)

print(date_of_interest)
print(eight_months)
```

from:
[How do I calculate the date six months from the current date using the datetime Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546321/how-do-i-calculate-the-date-six-months-from-the-current-date-using-the-datetime)

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52478319/9450678