# How do I calculate the date Three months from a input date using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the datetime Python module. I am looking to calculate the date 3 months from the input date. Can you help me to get out of this issue.Thanks in advance

```
import datetime
today = "2022-02-24"

three = today + datetime.timedelta(30*3)
print (three)
```

Also I tried using "relativedelta"

Comment: timedelta can represent duration in days, hours, seconds so you can say days=90 for 90 days.  How do you want to handle months with different # days (e.g. 1-Jan + 90 days is not 1-Mar) ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546321/how-do-i-calculate-the-date-six-months-from-the-current-date-using-the-datetime

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to add a `timedelta` to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a `timedelta` to a string, you need to add it to a `datetime` instance

Note that 90 days, isn't really 3 months

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = "2022-02-24"
three = datetime.strptime(today, "%Y-%m-%d") + timedelta(30 * 3)
print(three)  # 2022-05-25 00:00:00

three = datetime.today() + timedelta(30 * 3)
print(three)  # 2022-05-24 21:32:35.048700
```

Comment: if I put "2022-02-24" am getting "2022-05-25".Is to possible to get  "2022-05-24" like this.Only month and year need to change

Answer (score 1):

With `relativedelta` of `dateutil` package, you can use:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date

three = date.today() + relativedelta(months=3)
```

Output:

```
>>> three
datetime.date(2022, 5, 23)
```

Comment: assume the date was 2020-03-01, and we do months=1, why do we miss getting 2020-01-30 or 2020-01-31?