# How to get the next date in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, datediff

I have two series in my dataframe to calculate next payment date, one is start date, the other is payment frequency.

How to get the next payment date in python?

For example, the start date is 2021/12/21, and the payment frequency is 6 months, I want to get the next payment date of 2022/6/21.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546321/how-do-i-calculate-the-date-six-months-from-the-current-date-using-the-datetime

Answer (score 1):

Using the `parser` module from `dateutil` library you can parse the start date text into a `datetime.datetime` object. With `relativedelta` from the same library you can advance time in that datetime object. Here's an code example:

```
from dateutil import parser
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

start_date = parser.parse("2021/12/21")
end_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=+6)

print(start_date)
print(end_date)
```

Output:

```
2021-12-21 00:00:00
2022-06-21 00:00:00
```